# Strange answer after executing n++

Tags: c#

Why is the value of int d 25 and not 26 after executing the following code snippet?

```
int n = 20;
int d = n++ + 5;

Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ++i and i++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: See also: https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/development-testing-blog/2013/09/24/c-c-and-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`n++` is the "post-increment operator", which only increments the value **after** its initial value has been used in the surrounding expression.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int d = n + 5;
n = n + 1;
```

To increment the value **before** its value gets used, use `++n`, the pre-increment operator.

Comment: +1 for breaking out the equivalent surgarless syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need to use `++n` to use the incremented value in that expression.

See, in the expression tree it's not incrementing `n` and then using that value in the addition because `n++` returns the value of `n` but increments it for the next expression used.

However, `++n` will actually return the incremented value of `n` for this expression.

Therefore, `n++ + 5` yields `25` whereas `++n + 5` yields `26`.

Answer (score 2):

`n++` means execute the adition after the operation, so first d will equal to `n+5` and then `n` will get raised.

Answer (score 2):

Because `n++` will first assign the value and after the completion of iteration it will increment thats the reason its giving 25

Hence,

```
int d= n++ +  5;
```

is interpreted as

```
int d = n +  5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of you are using Postfix express

```
int d = n++ + 5;
```

where compiler first assign value to d, but in following

```
int d = ++n + 5;
```

You will got d's value 26

Answer (score 1):

`++`:post increment operator.

The result of the postﬁx ++ operator is the value of the operand. After the result is
obtained, the value of the operand is incremented

Hence,

```
int d= n++ +  5;
```

is interpreted as

```
int d = n +  5;
```

after execution of the above interpretaion. `n` is incremented by 1.