# Feel kind of confused by the book "Programming in C" (Stephen Kochan)

Tags: c, styles

I've been teaching myself in C programming with the book recommended by a friend who is great in C. The book title is "Programming in C" by Stephen Kochan.

I have a background in Java, and I feel a little bit crazy with the way the codes were written in Stephen's book. For example, the following code, in which I commented my confusion. Maybe I'm missing something important here, so I'm looking to hear some inputs about the correct way of coding in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int *int_pointer)
{
  *int_pointer = 100;
}

int main(void)
{
  void test(int *int_pointer);  // why call the test() function here without any real argument? what's the point?
  int i = 50, *p = &i;

  printf("Before the call to test i = %i\n", i);

  test(p);
  printf("After the call to test i = %i\n", i);

  int t;
  for (t = 0; t < 5; ++t)   // I'm more used to "t++" in a loop like this. As I know ++t is different than t++ in some cases. Writting ++t in a loop just drives me crazy
  {
    if (4 == t)  // isn't it normal to write "t == 4" ?? this is driving me crazy again!
        printf("skip the number %i\n", t);
    else
        printf("the value of t is now %i\n", t);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void test(int *int_pointer);` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

> why call the `test()` function here without any real argument? what's the point?

Here `test` is declared as function (with `void` return type) which expects an argument of the type a pointer to `int`.

> I'm more used to "t++" in a loop like this. As I know ++t is different than t++ in some cases. Writting ++t in a loop just drives me crazy

Note that, when incrementing or decrementing a variable in a statement by itself (`t++;` or `++t`), the pre-increment and post-increment have same effect.
The difference can be seen when these expression appears in a large or complex expressions ( `int x = t++` and `int x = ++t` have different results for the same value of `t`).

> isn't it normal to write "t == 4" ?? this is driving me crazy again!

`4 == t` is much safer than `t == 4`, although both have same meaning. In case of `t == 4`, if user type accidentally `t = 4` then compiler would not going to throw any error and you may get erroneous result. While in case of `4 == t`, if user accidentally type `4 = t` then compiler would through you a warning like:

```
 lvalue is required as left operand of assignment operator.
```

Comment: You might note on that first comment that that is a function declaration, not a call.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about pointers then you will understand that a pointer to an int has been passed as an argument here...

```
void test(int *int_pointer);
```

You can see the difference between `++t` and `t++` nicely explained in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) . It doesn't make a difference in this code. Result will be the same.

`if(4 == t)` is same as `if(t == 4)` . Just different styles in writing. `4 == t` is mostly used to avoid typing `=` instead of `==`. Compiler will complain if you write `4 = t` but wont complain if you write `t = 4`

Answer (score 1):

// why call the test() function here without any real argument? what's the point?
It is not a call, it is function declaration. Completely unnecessary at this location, since the function is defined few lines before. In real world such declarations are not used often.

// I'm more used to "t++" in a loop like this. As I know ++t is different than t++ in some cases. Writting ++t in a loop just drives me crazy
In this case they are equivalent, but if you think of going to C++ it is better to switch completely to ++t form, since there in some cases (e.g. with iterators) it makes difference.

// isn't it normal to write "t == 4" ?? this is driving me crazy again!
Some people tend to use 4 == t to avoid a problem when `t = 4` is used instead of `t == 4` (both are valid in C as `if` condition). Since all normal compilers signal a warning for `t = 4` anyway, `4 == t` is rather unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`void test(int *int_pointer);` is a function prototype. It's not required in this particular instance since the function is defined above `main()` but you would need it (though not necessarily in the function body) if `test` was defined later in the file. (Some folk rely on implicit declaration but let's not get into that here.)

`++t` will never be slower than `t++` since, conceptually, the latter has to store and return the previous value. (Most compilers will optimise the copy out, although I prefer not to rely on that: I *always* use `++t` but plenty of experienced programmers don't.)

`4 == t` is often used in place of `t == 4` in case you accidentally omit one of the `=`. It's easily done but once you've spent a day or two hunting down a bug caused by a single `=` in place of `==` you won't ever do it again! `4  = t` will generate a compile error but `t = 4` is actually an *expression* of value 4 which will compare `true` and *assigns* the value of `4` to `t`: a particularly dangerous side-effect. Personally though I find `4 == t` obfuscating.