# Output of this Java program

Tags: java, output

This is not my code and I know this is not the right way to write this. I was asked this in an online test.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int x = 10;
        x = x++ * ++x;
        System.out.println(x);
     }
}
```

Ouptut is 120. I don't understand why. Should it not be 132/121 ? Is it JVM dependent?

Comment: think ab out the post and pre application of ++

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ he means `132` **or** `121`

Comment: FYI, Java defines the evaluation order, so that this is not JVM dependent.  But don't try this C or C++, where the results could be compiler-dependent.  (Not sure about JavaScript, PHP, C#.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x++` is evaluated first.  It's post-increment, so `10` is the value of the expression, then `x` is incremented to `11`.

`++x` is evaluated next.  It's pre-increment, so `x` is incremented to `12` and `12` is the value of the expression.

The rest is simple multiplication, and 10 * 12 = 120.

This behavior is not dependent on which JVM is used; all JVMs must behave this way, as specified by the Java Language Specification.

The [JLS, Section 15.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) covers post-increment expressions:

> The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable *before* the new value is stored.

The [JLS, Section 15.15.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1) covers pre-increment expressions:

> The value of the prefix increment expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error dealing with the meanings of `i++` and `++i`.

See [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i),

Answer (score 0):

It is perfect, x++ will make it 10 due to `post increment` at the time of execution and will become 11 after and ++x will make it 12 at instance due to `preincrement`. so the output would be 120