# debugging (i!=t++) vs ( t++!=i)

Tags: java, debugging

I was solving some problem where I have to use (i!=t++) condition. Unfortunately using this condition gave TLE. But when I use (t++!=i) instead it was successfully submitted. I think both conditions are the same wrt to below program. The output of the program on my compiler is 
5259
3 which is time taken by by first and second loop respectively
I can not find the difference between the two conditions. Of course there is bug somewhere that i cannot find

```
void test()
{
    long b=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<100001;i++) {
        int t=0;
        while (i!=t++)
        {
            int x=34;
            x++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-b);

    b=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i=0;i<100001;i++) {
        int t=0;
        while (t++!=i)
        {
            int x=34;
            x--;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does TLE stand for?

Comment: Time limited Exceeded

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5413593/5617860

Comment: @Omore That's not the issue.  `t++` is used in both places.

Comment: I've duplicated these results, and also verified that it's not just because the first loop runs first - the `while (i!=t++)` is slower even if I put it after the other loop.  Also, I verified that both loops run the same number of times by adding counters.

Comment: both are taking exactly the same time

Comment: @Omore but I didn't even use ++t.  Problem is with swapping the i and t++

Comment: @TanujYadav That's very interesting.  Maybe it depends on something like what Java version is being used?  My Java version is 1.8.0_111.

Comment: i tried it in c++ :p

Comment: @DM ya I have also tried all of that. Both loops run exactly the same

Comment: @DM My java version is 1.8.0_111.

Comment: @NishantSharma Did you by any chance do this on an online compiler? Because if i shorten the loops both give the same time... Maybe you do not have enough time left? It takes almost 5 second to complet the first loop. Some online compilers/coding excercised have a compilation limit of how many time a program may run.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander I run it on IDE and also on online compiler both giving almost same result. Also even if I put lower loop at the top result remain the same but swapped

Comment: So it doesn't work on your IDE aswell? how can that run out of time?

Comment: @GijsDenHollander Even if it doesn't "time out", one loop takes significantly longer than the other, even though they are logically identical.

Comment: @GijsDenHollander Even if there is any case of compilation limit swapping the loops should not have swap the result.  also my program should not have reached the compilation limit even on online ones. also C++ code runs almost fine

Comment: @DM can you please elborate that. how can two similar logical loops take different time

Comment: Just stopping by to mention that I have replicated the results as well. 2876 for the first loop, 4 for second. JVM version: 1.8.0_121.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a partial answer, and future investigations are necessary. But, for the time being, the answer is - **it is the effect of JIT optimisation**. Also, note that microbenchmarks are not the best option for performance testing, especially with dynamically-compiled languages like Java (see, for example, [this guru paper](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp02225/)).

I am using Windows 10 Home, `java -version` prints:

> java version "1.8.0_121"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

I have restructured your code as follows and added `x` as external counter to assure the loops are not optimized away:

```
void test1() {
    int x = 0;
    long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_001; i++) {
        int t = 0;
        while (i != t++) {
            x++;
        }
    }
    long b1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("T(test1) = " + (b1 - b));
    System.out.println("x(test1) = " + x);
}

void test2() {
    int x=0;
    long b = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100001; i++) {
        int t = 0;
        while (t++ != i) {
            x++;
        }
    }
    long b1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("T(test2) = " + (b1 - b));
    System.out.println("x(test2) = " + x);
}
```

Each function is called twice:

```
t.test1();
t.test1();
t.test2();
t.test2();
```

Ok, let's see the results for standard `java Test` invocation (no other interpeter arguments are supplied):

> T(test1) = 3745
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test1) = 0
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 5
>   x(test2) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 0
>   x(test2) = 705082704

As you can see, after the second invocations, the running times equal to 0 in both cases. The same happens even if we change `int x = 0` initialisation to `int x = new Random().nextInt()` to assure that the second invocation results are not cached or something. Generally, one should "warmup" the Java interpreter before doing measurements, i.e. measure the code performance twice in the same run and throw-away the first result, so that one assures that optimisations are in place. But that's the luxury you don't have when solving online-judges exercises.

Now for the other part. Oracle's JDK has a `-Xint` interpreter switch, which turns off JIT completely. Let's use it and see what happens. I've used `-XX:+PrintCompilation` flag as well to assure that no compilation whatsoever is taking place (i.e. interpreter was invoked as `java -XX:+PrintCompilation -Xint Test`; if no additional diagnostics are printed that means the code was not compiled):

> T(test1) = 56610
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test1) = 55635
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 60247
>   x(test2) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 58249
>   x(test2) = 705082704

Two observations: now the task takes ages and the results are similar across all invocations. More investigation has to be done to discover why the two codes are optimised by JIT differently.

EDIT: *Fun with JIT part 2*

So, I went on trying different compilation options. Generally speaking, there are two types of compilers that JIT uses. C1 (client) compiler is aimed at giving faster JVM startup times but is not as fast as C2 (server) compiler. 64-bit Java 8 JVM I used seems to make server the only easily-available option (see [this FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_download); however different compilation levels can still be chosen with `-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=` flag; for brevity, I won't paste the results I got using it, but they support the thesis that it's the server compiler version that makes the first invocation of `test2` faster).

I happen to have 32-bit JRE on my machine as well. It does not support server compiler and gives the following version info:

> java version "1.8.0_121"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

The results for this JVM are as follows:

> T(test1) = 3947
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test1) = 3985
>   x(test1) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 4031
>   x(test2) = 705082704
>   T(test2) = 4172
>   x(test2) = 705082704

Answer (score 0):

So I have tested your code and checked how long it runs. Whith the following results (the time in millisecond for loop 1 and 2):

```
 time1   time2 
 175.2   171.0
 189.6   187.1
 162.1   164.2
 162.3   162.1
 162.3   166.0
```

Both loops run in the same time.

**Here is the code**

```
private static void test()
  {
    long b;

    float time1=0;
    float time2=0;

    int x=0;
    for(int l=0;l<10;l++) {
        b=System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i=0;i<20001;i++) {
          int t=0;
          while (i!=t++)
            {
            x++;
            }
        }


        time1+=System.currentTimeMillis()-b;

        b=System.currentTimeMillis();
        x=0;
        for(int i=0;i<20001;i++) 
            {
            int t=0;
            while (t++!=i) 
                {
                    x++;
                }


        }

    time2+=System.currentTimeMillis()-b;

    }

    time1/=10;
    time2/=10 ;   
    System.out.println(time1);  
    System.out.println(time2);
}
```

I am not sure why you think that the statements would chance the situations. But I think that your program ran out of time on your online compiler (which has an end time). After wich you changed the arguments and thought that it worked now. 
This could probably be caused by that your code was warmed up, wich may decrease the rune time slightly of a program. But this is just guessing....And should not work as an answer.

Pleas test the above code for yourself.

To answer youre question both logical epressions are the same. Although there is a slight difference in the post-fix i++ (copy the value, increment the current value, yields the copy) and the prefix ++i (increment the current value and yields the result). Where the second does have one less operation. But this should not result in a different computation time.

Look at this post [Why is "while (i++ < n) {}" significantly slower than "while (++i < n) {}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322679/why-is-while-i-n-significantly-slower-than-while-i-n) for an explanation why youre IDE give some strange results.

Comment: I ran your code and got times of 193.8 and 0.5.  What Java version do you have?

Answer (score -1):

My best guess here is that it's a quirk of how the bytecode is being generated and/or executed.

Computer processors have a limited number of registers they can use to store the values they are working on at any given time.  It's possible that the variables are being placed in different registers based on which one appears first.  And if the variables are in different registers to start out, that might impact which one is removed to make room for something else.

If a value is not in a register when it is later needed, the processor will have to go get it from the computer's memory (or the processor's cache), which takes more time than if it was already in a register.

There's also things where the processor can try to begin to execute one statement before another is finished.  But this can be interrupted if a value changes.  If the `t++` happens very soon before it tries to load `t` again, perhaps the processor is being interrupted and has to start the instruction from scratch.  (However, I don't think this is the main reason for what's happening; it wouldn't have such a large effect.)

Maybe it's just a matter of some optimization that the Java compiler sees it can do in one instance and not the other.

Comment: It dont think this is the reason. what if we create 2 different program for each loop. Then also the exeution time give very large difference. and I didnt get what were you trying to say in the 4th para, t and t++ . I mean both of the loops have t++ . So you are trying to say, the problem is due to parallel processing