# This recursive function become infinite loop. Why?

Tags: loops, recursion, infinite-loop

### /* if i change line 10 to "print_array_1(a, n, ++i)" or "print_array_1(a, n, i+1)", then this code runs well.*/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

void print_array_1(int a[], int n , int i)        // n = size of array,   i = start index
{
    if(i>=n) return;
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    print_array_1(a, n, i++);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int n = 5;
    print_array_1(arr, n, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is C, you should use `++i`. Why?

`i++` increments i, but returns `i`.
`++i` increments i and returns `1+1`.

With `i++`, you keep calling the recursion function with the same `i` value.

- [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 0):

i++ increments i *after* use in the call to print_array_1, so every call gets i=0.

Comment: Here is more information about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i