# Basic integer incrementation with unexpected results

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

The image is a screenshot from a Swift playground -> code on the left, log (if you can call it that) on the right.

I suppose what I expected to happen was that line 8 would result in 1 because, you know, 0 + 1 = 1

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

[image]

now with println

[image]

p.s. before you say anything about it, I understand semi-colons are useless now, it's habit since i'm just today deciding to learn Swift coming from Obj-C.

Comment: Go check out the difference between `i++` and `++i`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From here:[What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

- ++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value.
- i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

The playground prints the **return value** of that line, and in the `i++` case, it will return `i`'s original value and so prints it, *then* increments it.

Comment: This is not specific to swift, this is true of every language I know.

Comment: @achi actually, this is a pretty standard syntax that is in C as well as several other languages.

Answer (score 0):

`++i` Known as the pre-increment operator. If used in a statement will increment the value of `i` by `1`, and then use the incremented value to evaluate the statement.

```
int i = 0;
println(++i); /* output 1 */ 
println(i); /* output 1 */
```

`b++` Known as the post-increment operator. If used in a statement will use the current value of `b`, and once the statement is evaluated, it then increments the value of `b` by `1`.

```
int b = 0;
println(b++); /* output 0 */
println(b); /* output 1 */
```

Note that when you use the pre and post increment operator are used by themselves the behave the same way

```
int y = 0;
int z = 0; 
++y; 
z++;
println(y); /* output 1 */
println(z); /* output 1 */
```