# Why is "ref" not assigning updated value to the next field?

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, ref, post-increment

I've found a really cool feature of a compilator. However, I cannot understand logic of this behaviour.

```
static int IncrementValue(ref int i) { return i++;}
```

and Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = IncrementValue(ref a);
    Console.WriteLine(a+b);
}
```

The output is 5.

My question is:

1. Why is "b" field equal 2? (In my view, it ought to be 3 as "ref" keyword is not copying by value, but the keyword takes field by value. Consequently, "b" should be as "a+1")

Comment: You are aware that the *return value* of `i++` is the *non-incremented value*? Maybe you meant to write `return ++i;`?

Comment: This is not a "cool feature". __`++`__ is obscure, as you have found out.

Comment: For some strange reason people use i++ more often than ++i, where ++i is in many case more correct and leads to less errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you wrote it as;

```
return i++
```

This will *still* return `2` as a value but it will increase `a` value to `3` after the expression.

If you wrote it as;

```
return ++i
```

This will return incremented value which is `3`, and since `a` will be `3` after the execute it, it will be printed `6` as a result.

Further reading

- [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: Not really *after it returns*, but after the expression has determined its value. Basically the statement will be executed as follows: Read the current value of `i`, then increment `i`, then return the value we read before we incremented it. Returning is still the last thing that is done in that method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, _after the expression_ is much clear explanation. Since English is not my mother language, sometimes I can't express myself properly.

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is the *post* increment operator. It will increment the value afterwards, instead of before the value is returned.

Change `i++` to `++i` to make it increment before the value is returned, or increment the value in a separate statement and then return the value:

```
static int IncrementValue(ref int i) { return ++i; }
```

Or:

```
static int IncrementValue(ref int i) { i++; return i; }
```

(The reason you see different values when returning the integer, is that the result is copied. It is not a reference, else the return statement would not be useful at all).