# php programmatically select fields without looping

Tags: php, variables

I have two arrays,

```
$col = array(1,3,5,7,10...)
 $data = array(1000 by 1000)
```

my program is:

```
$result = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($data); ++i){
    for($j=0; $j<count($col); ++j){
         $result .= ",".$data[$j]
    }
$result .= "<br>";
}
echo $result;
```

> Question is how can I `eliminate` the `inner loop` or the `j loop`?

Since the `$col` array already know which index to pick, how can I format a variable of a variable so that j loop can be replace by

```
$result = $data[1st element in $col].","$data[2nd element in $col].","...;
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code and question? can you also put what is expected?

Comment: Sorry Iet me put it in a more readable form.

Comment: `$data = array(1000 by 1000)`what it means?

Answer (score 0):

it's have different meaning of `++$i` and `$i++`,

**change the ++i and ++j to $i++ and  $j++**

```
$result = "";
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($col); $j++){
         $result .= ",".$data[$j]
    }
$result .= "<br>";
}
echo $result;
```

reference : [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)