# $.each index initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery

As we know the index of $.each will start from zero. I want to print the index from 1 to 10, as I have 10 array.

```
$.each(myArr, function(i){
console.log(i++);
}
```

why is it I'm getting from 0 still?

Comment: try console.log(++i); // A classical example of prefix and postfix operator

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: @Satya, you don't need to increment it manually though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ++ operator AFTER the variable increases that variable after the current call is finished (in your case, after the console log call), which is why you see it starting from 0.

Since it's an index, there's no need for you to manually increase its value, but a simple `console.log(i+1);` would work just fine.

Otherwise, you can increase it BEFORE the current call, by putting ++ before the variable, as @Satya said in the comments.

---

See it here:

```js
var myArr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

$.each(myArr, function(i){
  console.log(i+1);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if i want to start at 2?

Comment: It would be `console.log(i + 2);` in that case... Think of it as `i + startingNumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$.each(myArr, function(i){
console.log(++i);
})
```

This is a difference between prefix and postfix operator. Prefix operator increases the value after the current operation is done. Postfix operator increases the value first and executes the current statement. This above code is for just explaining things.

As @Ghazgkull suggested, it is better to use i+1 which conveys the indent of the code.

Comment: Why does it work? Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: This works but it's not good code. When programmers see `++` the natural assumption is that you're incrementing some value. Although it might work, it looks like a bug.

Comment: what if i want to start at 2?

Answer (score 0):

When the ++ operator is applied on the right side of the variable (`i++`), the current value before incrementing is used. You should use `++i` if you want to get the value after incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

`$.each()` increments the value for you. You don't need to increment it yourself. Your code should be:

```
$.each(myArr, function(i) {
    console.log(i + 1);
}
```

Even if `++i` works in this case, you shouldn't use an incrementor here. To any experienced programmer, it will look like you're trying to increment a value in a way that doesn't make sense. Using `i + 1` makes it clear that you're simply computing a value.

Comment: I said that like 5 minutes ago.

Comment: Not sure why my answer is downvoted. It's correct and steers the OP toward better style...