# Conditional expression behavior incorrect

Tags: c++, c++11

I would expect that the two conditionals would yield the same answer (nEntries = 0). I don't understand why it doesn't.

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <iomanip>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    int main() {
       int nEntries = 1;
       nEntries = (nEntries)? nEntries--: nEntries;
       cout << "nEntries = " << nEntries << endl;   // nEntries = 1
       nEntries = 1;
       if (nEntries) nEntries--;                    // nEntries = 0
       cout << "nEntries = " << nEntries << endl;
       return 0;
}
```

It looks like the conditional expression is doing:

```
if (nEntries) tmp = nEntries--;
```

art

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ++i and i++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: Where did `tmp` come from, in your mind?

Answer (score 4):

```
nEntries = (nEntries)? nEntries--: nEntries; // statement 1
// ...
if (nEntries) nEntries--;  // statement 2
```

1 and 2 are *not* equivalent statements, so there is no reason to expect them to behave equivalently.

```
// statement 3, equivalent with statement 1
if (nEntries)
     nEntries = nEntries--; // Assignment and decrement are unsequenced modifications.
                            // The behaviour is undefined.
else
     nEntries = nEntries; // this is pointless...
```

As you can see, statement 1 and it's equivalent 3 have undefined behaviour, so you cannot expect it to behave in any particular way.

In case you aren't familiar with unsequenced modification being undefined, see [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/2079303)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am unfamiliar with unsequenced behavior and will attempt to get smarter. Thanks.