# Index Out of Bounds Exception, the function i wrote is down

Tags: java, vector

i wrote a function that take a string text and can access vector v that contains
character. it loops on the text[i]. if found any char that is in v, then it should take text[i] and put it in the v2(a new vector) with the same index found in v? and out of bound exception is printed to me any help?

```
     public void encode( StringBuffer text) // need test
       {
           int temp,temp3;
           boolean t;
           String temp2;
           int j=0;
           int sizeoftext=text.length()-1;

           do
           {
           for(int i=v.size()-1;i>-1;--i) // loop on text
           {
               temp=(v.elementAt(i)).length();// length of the longest word in dictionary
               temp2=text.substring(j, j+temp); //string with the same length of temp
               if((v.elementAt(i).equals(temp2)))// check if they r equal
                   {   

 HERE IS THE PROBLEM          >>            v2.add(i,temp2); // if yes add it to v2
                       temp3=temp+1;// increase size to take the nxt char
                       v.addElement(text.substring(j,temp3)); //add it to the dictionay
                      // v2.trimToSize();
                      // v.trimToSize();
                   }

           }

           temp3=temp=0;
           ++j;
           --sizeoftext;


           }while(sizeoftext>-1);



       }
```

Comment: what is the value of `text` and `v` that you entered?

Comment: for example text= aaaabbbccc , v= abc .

Comment: its should be a compression file function

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for(int i=v.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
```

instead of

```
for(int i=v.size()-1;i>-1;--i)
```

Comment: the problem is not in the loop i swear

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(int i=v.size()-1;i>-1;--i)
```

to

```
for(int i=v.size()-1;i>=0;i--)
```

This is important because **i--** and **--i** does not produce the same result and make the for to process in different manner the indexes.

This is explained here: [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) (Other language question but the response about i++ vs ++i is the same)