# How do i solve this array and loop? correct output but

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My objective is to write a loop that sets newScores to oldScores shifted once left, with element 0 copied to the end.

**Edit**: Here's my main problem, I initialized `newScores[3] = oldScores[0];` but the thing is the for loop makes `i = 4` when there's no oldScores[4] or newScores[4] but since I initialized newScores[3] to oldScores[0] it compiles and runs, but the problem is that [4] is not in the array at all. How do i get rid of this problem? I'm so close but so far away it's bugging me.

Example:

```
If oldScores = {10, 20, 30, 40}, then newScores = {20, 30, 40, 10}
```

Funny thing is I have the correct output but the learning website I'm using it tells me that I have the correct output but it also displays this "Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.). Tests aborted.".

```
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
      int[] oldScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int[] newScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
      int i = 0;

      oldScores[0] = 10;
      oldScores[1] = 20;
      oldScores[2] = 30;
      oldScores[3] = 40;
      newScores[3] = oldScores[0];
      for(i=0; i<SCORES_SIZE-1; i++){
         newScores[i] = oldScores[i +1];
      }

      for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
         System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please tag the question with appropriate language

Comment: Please tag the answer that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the second loop where you have ++i.  i++ and ++i have two different meanings.  Here is a link to describe the meanings to you.  [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i).  If you change that, you should not get the error any more.  Below is the change in your code.

```
public class StudentScores {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
  final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
  int[] oldScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int[] newScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int i = 0;

  oldScores[0] = 10;
  oldScores[1] = 20;
  oldScores[2] = 30;
  oldScores[3] = 40;
  newScores[3] = oldScores[0];
  for(i=0; i<SCORES_SIZE-1; i++){
     newScores[i] = oldScores[i +1];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++) {
     System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();

  return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you are incrementing i prior to using it i.e. ++i

What that means is, i will be incremented before your System.out in the loop.  Since you intialized i to 0, the first index it will print is of 1 (not 0).  It will try to print

```
newScores[1]
newScores[2]
newScores[3]
newScores[4]
```

The last will result in an exception (invalid index).  Change the for loop to

```
for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++) {
```

(where i is incremented after use)

Comment: Oh guys i forgot to mention that for this exercise. The only place were i can place my solution is right after the line oldScores[3] = 40; and before the line for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++) {... sorry for the troubles

Comment: I get the correct answer and it compiles and runs on my IDE on jGrasp but on the learning website that im using (zybooks) it says i have the correct answer, but "  Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.).
Tests aborted." so basically the program complies and runs as intended but the learning website is basically saying im doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using i++ and ++i in wrong way.
**First loop**: newScores array index from 0 to 2 and increase 1 each time.
 
**Second loop**: you are trying to print newScores but loop using ++i. It means that newScores index will be printed from 1 to 3.
=> error at index 3.
Solution: replace second loop by
`for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE - 1; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple change to make your code work

```
oldScores[0] = 10;
      oldScores[1] = 20;
      oldScores[2] = 30;
      oldScores[3] = 40;
      newScores[3] = oldScores[0];
      for(i=0; i<SCORES_SIZE-1; i++){
         newScores[i] = oldScores[i +1];
      }
 /* REMOVE THIS PART   
          for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
             System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
          }
*/TILL HERE

// USE THE FOLLOWING
for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++) {
     System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
```

Because you are increasing the value prior to its use which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

In order to overcome the  " Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.). Tests aborted." I used an if/else statement:

```
for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++)
   {
      if (i == (SCORES_SIZE - 1))
      {
         newScores[i] = oldScores[0];
      }
      else
      {
         newScores[i] = oldScores[i + 1];
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that will pass all the tests:

```
  newScores[newScores.length -1] = oldScores[0];
  for (i = 0; i < oldScores.length - 1; i++) {
       newScores[i] = oldScores[i +1];  
  }

  for (i = 0; i < newScores.length; ++i) {
     System.out.print(newScores[i] + " ");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why re-inventing the wheel? Java API already allows doing this kind of stuff

1 - create method

```
    public static int[] switchScores(int[] oldScores){
      if(oldScores != null && oldScores.length > 0) {
        final int SIZE = oldScores.length;

        int[] newScores = new int[SIZE];
        newScores = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldScores, 1, SIZE+1);
        newScores[SIZE-1] = oldScores[0];

        return newScores;
      }
      else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null or Empty Array provided");
      }
   }
```

2 - run test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] input = new int[]{10, 20, 30, 40};
    System.out.println("Old scores : " + Arrays.toString(input));

    int[] output = switchScores(input);
    System.out.println("New scores : " + Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
for (i = 0; i < newScores.length; ++i) {

    // if statement to shift numbers to the left starting with the 2nd value
    if (i > 0) {
       newScores[i + 1] = oldScores[i];
    }

    // This will make the 1st value move and become newScores last value regardless of SCORES_SIZE value
    else {
       newScores[newScores.length - 1] = oldScores[i];
    }
}
```