# error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compiler-errors, dynamic-arrays

I know eventually I need to change trigram, whose one space contains 3 characters from the former string, into a dynamic array to solve this problem, but I tried to set my array's capacity large enough at first. However, when I compile my code, the error appears.

```
#error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string<char>'#
```

Code:

```
//global variable
int CAPACITY = 1000;

int main()
{
    //a string that reads in the language of the text
string language = "";
    //a string that reads in the file name of the text
string filename = "text.txt";
    //a string that reads in the original text characters
string original = "";
    //a string that reads in the modified original array
string rid_of_spaces = "";
    //an array with capacity that stores the trigrams
string trigrams[CAPACITY];
ifstream finput;
char c;
    //the length of an array
int sLength = 0;
    //the tracker for trigrams
int counter = 0;

cin >> language >> filename;
finput.open(filename.c_str());

while (finput.get(c)){
            //to test if the character is alpha
    if (isalpha(c)){
                    //change the alphabet to lowercase
        c = tolower(c);
                    //store the modified letter in the array
        original += c;
    }
            //change any other characters into a space
    else original += ' ';
}
sLength = original.length();

    //loop through the original array and change mutiple spaces into one 
for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++){
    if (isalpha(original[i]))
        rid_of_spaces += original[i];
    else {
        while (original[i] == ' ')
            i++;
        rid_of_spaces += ' ';
        rid_of_spaces += original[i];
    }
}
sLength = rid_of_spaces.length();

for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    trigrams[i] = 0;//initialize each element to 0

for (int i = 0; i < sLength - 2; i++){
    trigrams[counter] += rid_of_spaces[i] 
            + rid_of_spaces[i + 1]
            + rid_of_spaces[i + 2];
        counter++;
}

cout << filename << endl;

cout << original << endl;
cout << rid_of_spaces << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    cout << trigrams[i] << endl;

finput.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: How about using `std::vector` instead of the dynamic array?

Comment: try `const int CAPACITY`

Comment: @MikeCAT sorry but have no idea what that is

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is one of the C++ Standard Template Library and it provides variable-length array.

Comment: @MikeCAT oh, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable

```
int CAPACITY = 1000;
```

should be a constant

```
const int CAPACITY = 1000; // or with c++11 constexpr int CAPACITY = 1000;
```

for

```
string trigrams[CAPACITY];
```

because "ISO C++ forbids **variable** length array 'trigrams'" (g++ message)

And this

```
for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
    trigrams[i] = 0;//initialize each element to 0
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    trigrams[i] = "";//initialize each element to 0
```

You don't "initialize [strings] to 0" but with a **zero length** C-string. A zero length C-string is not an invalid 0-pointer, but a (valid) pointer to a char with value 0;

Generally, it's better not to use C-arrays if there are STL-means to avoid them; with c++11, `std::array<std::string, CAPACITY>` would be preferable here if you want to stay with the "capacity large enough" approach.

**[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0063ee796e9d9356) at Coliru's**

*I took the liberty to change all `i++` to `++i` in the `for`-loops' heads while at it; see eg. [What is the difference between ++i and i++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) for the rationale behind that.*

For a **dynamic** (without pre-defined bounds) array use `std::vector<std::string> trigrams;`,

[push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) your strings into that vector,
and for i- iterate

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < trigrams.size(); ++i) {/* ... */}
```

Or use the iterator-interface of `std::vector`, e.g.

```
std::for_each(trigrams.begin(), trigrams.end(), 
              some_function_or_functor_that_does_the_job);
```

(see std::foreach [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) ),

or with c++11 just

```
for (auto& s : trigrams) {/* ... */}
```

unless you need to customize the iteration like you do it inside your second loop.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `CAPACITY` is not a compile-time constant variable, and variable-length arrays are not in C++ (though some have it as an extension, but apparently not for all types).

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Turn the variable into a compile-time constant, either by making it `constexpr` alternatively `const` (for older compilers), or by defining it as a preprocessor macro.
2. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), like `std::vector<std::string> trigram(CAPACITY);`

My suggestion is that you use *both* solutions above, at least if you later need to resize the vector. If the size will be fixed at compile-time and never change, then use the first solution *and* use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C-style array:

```
constexpr std::size_t CAPACITY = 1000;

...

std::array<std::string, CAPACITY> trigram;
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of a C++ array must be a constant expression. You declare it as `int CAPACITY = 1000;`, which is not a constant expression. Adding a `const` qualifier solves the issue: `int const CAPACITY = 1000;`.

However, you should avoid plain arrays. Try using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you know the size at compile time, or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) if not.