# Finding min max in C++

Tags: c++

My exercise is as follows: Given a list of N integers, find its mean (as a double), maximum value, minimum value, and range. Your program will first ask for N, the number of integers in the list, which the user will input. Then the user will input N more numbers.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Input n: ";
    cin >> n;

    int first;             //**LINE NUMBER 1**
    cout << "No 1 is: ";
    cin >> first;
    int max = first;
    int min = first;

    for (int i=1; i<n;i++) //**LINE NUMBER 2**
    {
        int x;
        cout << "No " << i+1 << " is: ";
        cin >> x;
        first = x;         //**LINE NUMBER 3**
        if (max < x)
        {
           max = x;
        }
        if (min > x)
        {
           min = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "max is: " << max << endl;
    cout << "min is: " << min << endl;
    cout << "mean is: " << (double) (max+min)/2 << endl; //**LINE NUMBER 4**
    cout << "range is: " << max - min << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the solution is a bit different:

- For line number 1, it is `int first=0;` instead of `int first;`
- For line number 2, it is `for (int i=1; i<n;++i)` instead of `for (int i=1; i<n;i++)`
- For line number 3, it is `first += x;` instead of `first = x;`
- For line number 4, it is `cout << "mean is: " << (double) first/n<< endl;` instead of `cout << "mean is: " << (double) (max+min)/2 << endl;`

I tried some examples but both codes produce exactly the same results. Why is that? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: is this cheating? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bad0f9b90e22f17a

Comment: What do you mean? The method here doesn't use `iterator` and `algorithm`. This problem and its solution is from MIT open course: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/

Comment: The first two differences are stylistic.   As to the second two differences, your code will not compute the mean correctly if more than two values are input.     Clearly, your test cases were insufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well:

None of the lines are, per se, WRONG. More so, they are just preferably done another way. ie:

- `int first =0` just ensures that `first == 0` to begin with. `int first;` can cause problems because it is assigned, initially to an arbitrary number (whatever happens to be at the memory address that the variable points to)
- although `++i` and `i++` work the same way in for loops as an iterator, they have a very slight difference in other usages. read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)
- `first += x` is essentially `first = first + x` which more clearly outlines the difference between your code and it. This also makes it very clear why `int first = 0` is so important. If `first` was some random value, then the sum of all the numbers (which is what `first` is supposed to be) would be randomly assigned to start at a number, not always 0.
- this last one is the only one where you are, in fact, wrong. the `mean` is defined as the sum of all your data divided by the number of data points (same as `average`) where as the `median` is described as the middle point of the data, or the number that describes the middle point between the max and min of your data. Where you are calculating what you think is the `mean` is actually the `median`. The intricacy of this is that sometimes, depending on your data, the `mean = median`. For example, if your data is `3,4,5` then both the mean and median is equal to `4`

I hope this clarifies things for you :)

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! All clear to me, except a tiny point: after initializing `first == 0`, I overwrite it immediately by `cin >> first`. Does that really matter?

Comment: nope, I hadn't realized you did that. If you will initialize to a different value then having the `first = 0` is just a fail safe at that point.

Comment: so as far as I understand your comment, `int first = 0;` or `int first;` doesn't make any difference since I overwrite it immediately by `cin >> first;` Am I correct?

Comment: as far as I know, yes