# incorrect output on vector assignment?

Tags: c++11, vector, order-of-execution

Below code snippet is From Herb Sutter's blog [here](http://herbsutter.com/page/2/)

g++ outputs `10`. MSVC also does output `10`. Output could be different on different compilers.

I fail to understand how variable `i` is incremented. 
Can anyone explain me how come output is `10`, Is `10` really correct output?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{    
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 0 };
    int i = 0;
    v[i++] = i++;
    std::cout << v[0] << v[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

We'll leave the discussion of undefined behaviour out, and just focus on how your program arrives at the specified output.

First of all, lets state a fact:

- i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

from [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i).

Now, the line

```
v[i++] = i++;
```

evaluates, in your case, in the order "LHS" -> "RHS" -> assignment:

- LHS, v[i++]: i is incremented to 1 and i++ returns 0 to v[i++].
- RHS, i++: i now has value 1, but is incremented to 2, however i++ of RHS return 1.
- Assignment: From above, the assignment results in: v[0] = 1 (after which i has value 2).

Hence, printing v[0] and v[1] will evaluate in 1 (updated value) and 0 (as initialised), respectively.

Comment: Very nice approach to just explaining what goes on in the specific case, i reverted my dv! thumbs up.

Comment: Thanks! I hope the two downvoters on your answer will also reconsider after your edit, I think it's an relevant answer as well.

Comment: well they were right to dv at start, was not actually clear to me what was asked!

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem of order of execution and it is undefined due to c++11:

> 5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators
>
> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators
>   all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand. The result
>   in all cases is a bit-field if the left operand is a bit-field. *In
>   all cases, the assignment is sequenced **after** the value computation of
>   the right and left operands, and **before** the value computation of the
>   assignment expression*.

Simply put, the modification of the left argument is sequenced  after the value computation, but not of the side-effects of the computation, of both sides and before returning the reference to the object.

So the actions to be taken are

A. evaluate left side ( return value of expression i++ = 0 )

B. return reference to object ( return reference to object of expression v[i++] )

C. compute side-effects for left side i.e. i-> 1

D. compute side-effects for right side i.e. i-> 2

As you can see from the rule above it is not clear if the order is ABCD
or if it should be ACBD , since the order of the side-effects computation is not defined, if it should happen first for the left side or first for the right-side.

Comment: Just dv but no reason... Might be strategy?!