# How to stop a loop on itself function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an function and a conditional in that function and I will create loop by 4 times and break without without thinking any conditional.

Here is my idea

```
    function test (){

       var i = 0;

       $.ajax({
           setup:,
           success:function(data){
            if(data.resp ==true){
               if(i<= 4){
                test();
                 break;
                  return false;
               }
               }else{
               success;
               }
            }
       })
i++;
    }
```

I know this function will not work but I don't know how to do

Comment: And so, what is expected behaviour? Calling 4 ajax requests using recursive method or what???

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to stop after 4 calls of test method. For this to happen you have to make variable 'i' global.

Comment: Yes I will call only 4 times when data.res === true and I also break or stop this loop although data.res === true (still equal true)

Comment: Oh I will declare var i outside of function right

Comment: @ValentinS. don't set it global, set it as recursive method parameter instead

Comment: @A.Wolff

what you mean recursive method parameter instead?

Comment: I think you can pass a parameter for test function. function test(val). When you call test(), the `val` increase 1, so test(val+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call it recursively keeping `i` local, you could use:

```
(function test(i) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'uriThere.com',
    success: function(data) {
      if (i < 4 && data.resp == true) {
        test(++i);
      }
    }
  });
})(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either make the `var i = 0` variable outside of the function or try

```
function test (varI){

   var i = varI;

   $.ajax({
       setup:,
       success:function(data){
        if(data.resp ==true){
           if(i<= 4){
               test(++i);
               return false;
           }else{
               success;
           }
        }
    })
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong: `test(i++)` must be `test(++i)` and remove `i++;`

Comment: @A.Wolff what is difference betwen ++i and i++?

Comment: @HengSopheak http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i  In this answer, this works because extra `i++` and end of test() method, but what happen is that using `test(i++)` you pass value of `i` before it is incremented, while using `test(++i)` you pas incremanted value.

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks. Missed that. So used to incrementing in for loops :P