# what does ++ exactly mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, post-increment

i am learning Swift with a book aimed for people with little experience. One thing bothering me is the ++ syntax. The following is taken from the book:

```
var counter = 0
let incrementCounter = {
  counter++
}
incrementCounter()
incrementCounter()
incrementCounter()
incrementCounter()
incrementCounter()
```

the book said counter is 5.

but i typed these codes in an Xcode playground. It is 4!

i am confused.

Comment: counter++ can be translated to counter = counter + 1, or counter += 1

Comment: Note that the `++` and `--` operators [will be deprecated in Swift 2.2, and removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md).

Comment: Don't worry about ++ and --. These operators are deprecated and will be removed from swift 3.

Comment: because you are 'novice' in Swift, it would be better avoid to use ++ and / or -- operators. they will be removed from future versions of Swift language. instead use counter += 1 as recommended by Shai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post-increment and post-decrement operators increase (or decrease) the value of their operand by 1, but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment (or decrement) operation

So when you see playground, current value of counter is being printed.

[image: playground]

But after evaluation of function, the value of counter changes and you can see updated value on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` operator is an operator that is used in multiple languages - C, C++, Java (see the [C answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858/669586) for the same question)

It is called post-increment. It increments the given variable by one but after the current expression is evaluated. For example:

```
var x = 1
var y = 2 + x++
// the value of x is now 2 (has been incremented)
// the value of y is now 3 (2 + 1, x has been evaluated before increment)
```

This differs from the `++x` (pre-increment) operator:

```
var x = 1
var y = 2 + ++x
// the value of x is now 2 (has been incremented)
// the value of y is now 4 (2 + 4, x has been evaluated after increment)
```

Note the operator is **getting removed in the next version of Swift**, so you shouldn't use it anymore.

It's always better to just write `x += 1` instead of complex expressions with side effects.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `counter` after your five calls to the `incrementCounter` closure will be `5`, but the *return* of each call to `incrementCounter` will seemingly *"lag"*  one step behind. As Sulthan writes in his answer, this is due to `x++` being a post-increment operator: the result of the expression will be returned *prior*  to incrementation

```
var x = 0
print(x++) // 0
print(x)   // 1
```

Also, as I've written in my comment above, you shouldn't use the `++` and `--` operators as they will be [deprecated in Swift 2.2 and removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md). However, if you're interested in the details of post- vs pre-increment operator, you can find good answers here on SO tagged to other languages, but covering the same subject, e.g.

- [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

---

*It's worth mentioning, however, a point that **is** relevant to Swift > 2.1 however, and that don't really relate to the `++` operator specifically.*

When you initiate the closure `incrementCounter` as

```
var someOne : Int = 0
let incrementCounter = {
    someInt
}
```

The closure is implictly inferred to be of type `() -> Int`: a closure taking zero arguments but with a single return of type `Int`.

```
let incrementCounter: () -> Int = {
    return someInt
}
```

Hence, what you seemingly *"see"*  in you playground is the unused (non-assigned) return value of the call to `incrementCounter` closure; i.e., the result of the expression `incrementCounter()`.

[image]

Whereas the value of `counter` is never really printed in the right block of your playground (unless you write a line where the result of that line:s expression is `counter`).

Comment: dfri, do you like the decision that unary ++ and / or -- will be remove from the language? see my 'answer' and notes to it, please :-)

Comment: @user3441734 You bring up some interesting points. However hopefully the type inference for closures will become even better in future Swift (e.g. your third code block should compile and infer closure as `() -> Int`). Personally I like making use of side effects and hence expressions incl. e.g. `++`, but I fully understand Swifts decision to remove these, as general code safety is a poster-child for Swift, and I believe they wish to include also safety against _logical_ errors in their scope. In such case, `++` and `--` poses some danger when used or code-read by less experienced programmers.

Answer (score 2):

++ and -- before the identifier add/subtract one, and then return its value.
++ and -- after the identifier return its value, and then add/subtract 1.

[They were removed](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45185) in Swift 3.0, but you can add them back:

```
prefix operator --
prefix operator ++
postfix operator --
postfix operator ++

prefix func ++(_ a : inout Int) -> Int {
    a += 1
    return a
}
prefix func --(_ a : inout Int) -> Int {
    a -= 1
    return a
}
postfix func ++(_ a: inout Int) -> Int {
    defer { a += 1 }
    return a
}
postfix func --(_ a: inout Int) -> Int {
    defer { a -= 1 }
    return a
}

var a = 11
print(a++) // 11
print(a)   // 12

var b = 5
print(--b) // 4
print(b) // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

even though there are a lot of answers and all of them are clear i added this snippet to show you how to replace your code with 'new' syntax, where ++ and or -- are deprecated. at first your own code

```
var counter = 0
let incrementCounter = {
    counter++
}
let i0 = incrementCounter() // 0
let i1 = incrementCounter() // 1
// .....
```

how to rewrite it in future Swift's syntax? lets try the recommended replacement ...

```
var counter = 0
let ic = {
    counter += 1
}
let i0 = ic() // () aka Void !!!
let i1 = ic() // ()
```

but now the result of ic() is Void! Hm ... OK, the next attempt could looks like

```
var counter = 0
let ic = {
    counter += 1
    return counter
}
```

but now the code doesn't compile with error: unable to infer closure return type in current context :-), so we have to declare it (it was not necessary in our original version)

```
var counter = 0
let ic:()->Int = {
    counter += 1
    return counter
}
let i0 = ic() // 1
let i1 = ic() // 2
// .....
```

it works, but the results are not the same. that is because in original code ++ operator was used as post-increment operator. so, we need another adjustment of our 'new' version

```
var counter = 0
let ic:()->Int = {
    let ret = counter
    counter += 1
    return ret
}
let i0 = ic() // 0
let i1 = ic() // 1
// .....
```

yes, i would like to see my familiar unary ++ and / or -- will be also in the future versions of Swift

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you are doing is post increment.

First Learn the difference between Pre & Post Increment

1. In Post Increment, the value counter after increment contains **incremented value** *(i.e 5)*
   but if we return, then it will contain **old value** *(i.e 4)*.
2. In Pre Increment, both the value and return value is incremented.

Lets look into your code now,

`counter++` makes a copy, increases counter, and returns the copy (old value).

so if you print ***counter*** it will have incremented value *(i.e 5)* but, if you return counter *(i.e your doing so with incrementCounter)* it contains the old value *(i.e 4)*.

because of which ***incrementCounter*** only showing upto 4.

**CHECK OUTPUT**
 [image]
**Solution :**

change `counter++` to `++counter`

**CHECK OUTPUT**
[image]