# Why does ++ not add one to integer value

Tags: java, android

I have the following lines on my code:

```
   Log.d ("Playlist", "Current Song Number is: "+ currentSongNumber );

   currentSongNumber = currentSongNumber++;

   Log.d ("Playlist", "Current Song Number has changed to: "+ currentSongNumber );
```

But i get the result:

```
Current Song Number is: 2
Current Song Number has changed to: 2
```

So why has it not chaged to three does ++ only work when iterating?

Comment: Just type `currentSongNumber++`

Comment: It will read the current value 2, increment to 3 and then assign the previously read value 2 again.

Comment: Java's basics differences between var++ and ++var and assignment http://ideone.com/L4yx7d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The post-increment operator returns the *old* value and then it increments. By assigning back to the same variable, you discard the increment done to the variable.

So when you do

```
currentSongNumber = currentSongNumber++;
```

it is equivalent to the following code:

```
int oldValueOfCurrentSongNumber = currentSongNumber;
currentSongNumber = currentSongNumber + 1;
currentSongNumber = oldValueOfCurrentSongNumber;  // This is because of your assignment
```

Comment: why it assigning old value

Answer (score 1):

Try just this code:
currentSongNumber++;

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using post increment

so either try this

```
currentSongNumber = ++currentSongNumber;
```

or this

```
currentSongNumber++;
```

or this

```
++currentSongNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using post increment. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) to see the difference between pre-increment and post increment. In your code try pre increment.

`++currentSongNumber;`

This will give you desired output.

In your code, If you use `currentSongNumber = currentSongNumber++;` than first the value of `currentSongNumber` will be assigned to itself, which is same as previous and than the increment will take place.

Or you can just use simply `currentSongNumber = currentSongNumber+1;`, to avoid confusions.

Comment: `++` is syntactic sugar which allows to write only `currentSongNumber++`. You should not encourage the OP to write this useless affectation. `++currentSongNumber` or `currentSongNumber++` is enough here.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this at home:

```
Log.d ("Playlist", "Current Song Number is: "+ currentSongNumber );

  currentSongNumber++;

   Log.d ("Playlist", "Current Song Number has changed to: "+ currentSongNumber );
```