# Trying to run a code but terminal does not read the program

Tags: c++

This is probably a very easy problem, but I am studying while loops and I am trying to write a program that sums numbers from 50 to 100. This is my code that I wrote

```
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum=0;
    int val=1;
    while(50 <= val <= 100) {
        sum = sum + val;
        val = val + 1;
    }
    cout << "Sum is: " << sum <<  endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I was to compile the code and get a program, but each time I am trying to run the program on terminal is just goes idle. Is there something wrond with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Take a C++ book and learn from the scratch

Comment: Danh nailed it. But to give you a hint: your condition check in while is not correct.

Comment: Im completely new to C++. I have just started learning it this week. Sorry if this question is extremely elementary.

Comment: A hint: look what happens the first time you get in the while loop with val variable.

Comment: then you should at least check how to code logical statements in c++. The conditions of your while loop are logical statements and thats not how it works. AND you will never really enter the loop because your val is not in the desired range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the comments are valid. Please look at the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) for syntax and how to use [operators](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_operators.htm) and [loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_loop_types.htm).

I believe looking at some correct code is also a way to learn and hence posting this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 50; // Why not start from 50 itself, when you want sum(50-100)
    while (i <=100)
    {
        sum += i; // Same as sum = sum + i
        i++; // Same as i = i + 1
    }   
    cout<<sum<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Just a question, i++ is jut the same as ++i? so we can just as well write i=i+1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i will help

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Learner another advise is to look things up in google first and then if you fail to find a solution, then only ask here