# making images move itself through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a `div` where there are four images are displayed

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img1 = "<?php echo $product['image1']; ?>";
    var img2 = "<?php echo $product['image2']; ?>";
    var img3 = "<?php echo $product['image3']; ?>";
    var img4 = "<?php echo $product['image4']; ?>";
    $("#imgTag").fadeOut(8000).attr('src',img2);
 });
</script>

<div id="imageDiv">
   <img src="<?php echo $product['image1']; ?>" id="imgTag" />
</div>
```

Now I don't know how to put other images such as `img3` `img4` in `src` attribute and make it repeatable in infinite loop. Is there are any way to achieve this is jquery that images change in infinite iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = [
    1,
    "http://t2.uccdn.com/en/images/5/9/2/img_causes_of_fever_in_cats_9295_300_150.jpg",
    "http://www.jimvysearks.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/duck_surfing-300x150.jpg",
    "http://brightworkcoresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/beauty-in-nature-178495_1280-300x150.jpg",
    "http://www.educationworld.com/sites/default/files/Sun1.jpg"
  ];
  $("#imgTag").attr("src",images[images[0]]);
  (function loopImages() {
    ++images[0];
    if (images[0] == images.length) {images[0] = 1;}
    $("#imgTag").fadeOut(8000,function(){
      $(this).attr("src",images[images[0]]).fadeIn(500,function(){loopImages();});
    });
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imageDiv">
  <img src="" id="imgTag" />
</div>
```

**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9o2cw3hx/**

- I changed your individual `img1-4` vars into an array containing all the images.
- At index `[0]`, the array also contains the index-number of the current image.
- This index-number is incremented every time `loopImages()` is invoked (by itself, after the `src` is changed), in order to select the next image: `++images[0];`.
- After the last image in the array has been reached, the index-number is reset to the first image again: `if (images[0] == images.length) {images[0] = 1;}`.
- In order to get the function executed the first time, I enclosed it like this: `(function(){...})();`. That's called an [**IIFE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). This way, you don't have to manually invoke the function after declaring it.

*I removed the `src` from your HTML and instead set it with jQuery, but that's obviously not necessary the way you set it using PHP (your way is better).

And I changed the images to literal strings for demo purposes, you can change those back to PHP.*

---

### OPTION 2

Alternatively, you can send the index-number along as an argument when you invoke the function:

```
(function loopImages(i) {
  $("#imgTag").fadeOut(8000,function(){
    $(this).attr("src",images[i]).fadeIn(500,function(){loopImages(++i<images.length?i:0);});
  });
})(1);
```

- The first index in the `images` array, storing the index-number, is no longer necessary and can be removed (see the code snippet below).
- The two separate lines for incrementing the index-number, and the if-clause, are now combined into one inline [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) when the function invokes itself again: `loopImages(++i<images.length?i:0);`
  *It works like this:*
  **(1)** It [first increments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858/3407923) `i` and checks if that incremented value is still less than the array-length.
  **(2)** If it is, that (incremented) `i` is send along.
  **(3)** If it isn't, `0` is send along, resetting the index-number to the first image in the array.

Personally, I like this option better, as it's more concise.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = [
    "http://t2.uccdn.com/en/images/5/9/2/img_causes_of_fever_in_cats_9295_300_150.jpg",
    "http://www.jimvysearks.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/duck_surfing-300x150.jpg",
    "http://brightworkcoresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/beauty-in-nature-178495_1280-300x150.jpg",
    "http://www.educationworld.com/sites/default/files/Sun1.jpg"
  ];
  $("#imgTag").attr("src",images[0]);
  (function loopImages(i) {
    $("#imgTag").fadeOut(8000,function(){
      $(this).attr("src",images[i]).fadeIn(500,function(){loopImages(++i<images.length?i:0);});
    });
  })(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imageDiv">
  <img src="" id="imgTag" />
</div>
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9o2cw3hx/1/

Comment: +1000 for explaining the code! Really helped me thank you:)

Comment: @Wayne I added an alternative option, check it out, it's a lot cleaner

Comment: Yess saw that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function blick_image(){
    img1 ="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/arctichare.png";
    img2 = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png";
    img3 = "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png";
    var images = [img1,img2,img3];//creates array
    images.forEach(function(element,index,arr){
    alert(element);
    });
    }
    setInterval(blick_image,1000);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle here..https://jsfiddle.net/fmmp74zv/

Comment: `$("#imgTag").fadeOut(1000).attr('src',element).fadeIn();` I tried this! But it shows the same image

Comment: for more see here http://coolajax.net/create-image-blink-fade-in-effect-using-jquery-and-css3/