# Writing a recursive function in C

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion

I am studying how to program and have recently been working on a problem that calculates the total of 2 entered numbers from min to max. For example, if someone entered the numbers 4, 7. The calculation would be 4+5+6+7=22.

I've attempted what i think would be the definition of recSum but obviously it is wrong as I get a segmentation fault. What is wrong with my definition?

```
/* Define the recursive function */
int recSum (int x, int max)
{
int incrementalSum = 0;
if (x == max) 
{
   return x; /* Exit if summated lower to upper numbers */
}
else
{
   return (x + recSum(x++, max)); /* My recursive call */
}
} /* End of function call */
```

*new code is shown above, sorry, i used the wrong code.

Comment: If you are going to write code like if it were the 70s, at least make it readable.

Comment: Your `goto` construct is equivalent to a `while(1) { … }` loop. Loops are not recursion.

Comment: Do you want to write a recursive / or iterative solution for exercise purposes or aren't you aware of the formula to sum up all integers from 1-n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is this line:

```
return x + recSum(x++, max);
```

`x++` increments x but returns the previous value, so in the recursive calls it never increments and you never reach the base case. Like an infinite loop. You have to replace `x++` with `++x` in order to give any result, even though it won't be correct. `++x` is modifying x so it will alter the final sum of `x + recSum`. You'd better use:

```
return x + recSum(x + 1, max);
```

See [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 5):

Your code has 3 important problems

1. The expression

   ```
   incrementalSum = x + x++;
   ```

   is undefined, [read this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)
2. Your function is not recursive, a recursive function calls it self until a condition happens where it should end.
3. Also, noting that I am not an irrational "*don't ever use `goto` person*", this is precisely why some people advice against using `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following

```
int recSum(int x, int max)
{
    return max < x ? 0 : x + recSum( x + 1, max );
}
```

Or it would be even better to declare the return type of the function like `long long int`.

```
long long int recSum(int x, int max)
{
    return max < x ? 0 : x + recSum( x + 1, max );
}
```

The function can be called like

```
printf( "%lld\n", recSum( 4, 7 ) );
```

As for your function then it exits in the first call

```
int recSum(int x, int max)
{
    int incrementalSum = 0;
    recCall: if (x < max)
    return incrementalSum;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because usually it is called when x is less than max. So the function does not make sense. Moreover the function is not recursive because it does not call itself.

Comment: Excelent observation, this completes my answer. I think SO should have a method to allow answers to be merged and share the upvotes and downvotes among users.