# Show multiple images downloaded from a server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to download multiple images I've uploaded to a server and show in my scene in a gallery or in a slideshow. I've done the code below to download the images but I only get to show one image. How can I do to show multiple images downloaded from the server?

```
public void DownloadtheFiles()
    {

    List <string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++) {

        new GetUploadedRequest()

            .SetUploadId(photolist[i])
            .Send((response) =>
                {
                    StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url));
                } );
    }
    }

    public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl)
    {
        var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
        yield return www;
        downloadedImages = new Texture2D(200, 200);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(downloadedImages);
        imageLoaded.texture = downloadedImages as Texture;
    }
```

UPDATE 1: with the code bellow I show how I'd like to show them but it get the images from a folder path and I need to show the images I download from the server. How can I integrate this code to make the slideshow with the downloaded images?

```
public class ImageLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
[Tooltip("The folder where images will be loaded from")]
private string imagePath;

[SerializeField]
[Tooltip("The panel where new images will be added as children")]
private RectTransform content;

private List<Texture2D> textures;

private void Start()
{
    Application.runInBackground = true;
    StartCoroutine(LoadImages());
}

public IEnumerator LoadImages()
{
    textures = new List<Texture2D>();

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(imagePath);
    var files = di.GetFiles("*.png");

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Debug.Log(file.FullName);
        yield return LoadTextureAsync(file.FullName, AddLoadedTextureToCollection);
    }

    CreateImages();
}

private void AddLoadedTextureToCollection(Texture2D texture)
{
    textures.Add(texture);
}

private void CreateImages()
{
    foreach(var texture in textures)
    {
        GameObject imageObject = new GameObject("Image");
        imageObject.transform.SetParent(content);
        imageObject.AddComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
    }
}

public IEnumerator LoadTextureAsync(string originalFileName, Action<Texture2D> result)
{
    string fileToLoad = GetCleanFileName(originalFileName);

    Debug.Log("Loading Image from path: " + fileToLoad);

    WWW www = new WWW(fileToLoad);
    yield return www;

    Texture2D loadedTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1);

    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(loadedTexture);

    result(loadedTexture);
}

private static string GetCleanFileName(string originalFileName)
{
    string fileToLoad = originalFileName.Replace('\\', '/');

    if (fileToLoad.StartsWith("http") == false)
    {
        fileToLoad = string.Format("file://{0}", fileToLoad);
    }

    return fileToLoad;
}
}
```

UPDATE 2: I've created a ScrollView and HorizonatalLayoutGroup and I've applied the ImageLoader.cs of the UPDATE 1. I've added 4 images in the folder and these are a screenshots of the hierarchy and the result:

[image]

[image]

It works fine as a test, but the source of the images is a folder in my pc and I want to download the images of a server. How can I do it?

Comment: Where are you trying to show the image? UI? 2D or 3D Object?

Comment: I want to show all the images in UI

Comment: Hi @Programmer any idea to solve this?

Comment: What UI component? Maybe a screenshot of it in the Inspector tab? If you are trying to download multiple images,then you will need multiple of that UI component. How many do you have? Sorry this is not enough to help you.

Comment: @Programmer I'd like to show them in a dynamic image loading carousel.

Comment: carousel with UI object? Shouldn't carousel be a 3D Object? Sorry, at this moment, it's hard to understand what you are doing but what you have in your code is how to download images. I hope you find your answer. If you need help, you will have to add screenshot and explain where you want to display those images. Lack of that is why this hasn't been answered.

Comment: @Programmer I've updated my question with a example code of how I'd like to show the images but it get the images from a path and I need to show the images I download from the server. How can I integrate this code to make the slideshow with the downloaded images?

Comment: You can use HorizonatalLayoutGroup and the ScrollView to accomplish this.= dynamically. Just Google tutorial for them in Unity

Comment: @Programmer Yes, I know the tutorial, but I don't know how to show my downloaded images in the scrollview. Can you help me, please?

Comment: I want t help you and have been since my comments but you have not done anything that will require me to put an actual answer. Read my last comment. Use ScrollView and HorizonatalLayoutGroup to create this. Put an image in your folder for testing purposes.Create RawImage with that image and use that RawImage multiple times as a test to get the effect you mentioned your question with the help of ScrollView and HorizonatalLayoutGroup. No code required for all this. Once you do it, update your question to show what it looks like. Also show a screenshot of the Hierarchy tab of it.

Comment: @Programmer I just Updated my question above. It works fine as a test, but the source of the images is a folder in my pc and I want to download the images of a server as I told in my original question. How can I do it?

Comment: @Programmer Now it works fine!!! Thank you very much for  your patience with me !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have don all the required parts done by using `ScrollView` and `HorizonatalLayoutGroup`. Notice that I asked you to use the `RawImage` component but it seems like you are using the `Image` component. I recommended `RawImage` because lets you to avoid the use of `Sprite.Create` which is expensive. You can still use `Image` if you want.

The only thing you have to do now is to resize the `RawImage` until you are satisfied with its size. Create **one** prefab from that `RawImage`. Delete the Image/RawImage under the Content GameObject. You don't need them any longer.

Now, download your images from the server, instantiate a prefab from that RawImage prefab. *Finally, make that `RawImage` to be the child of the Content GameObject.* That's it. The `HorizonatalLayoutGroup` should automatically position it.

With your original code, below is how to do that. The `contentRef` variable is a reference to the Content GameObject which is under ScrollView. The `imgPrefab` variable is a reference to the `RawImage` prefab. Make sure to assign both from the Editor. Also, notice how I added and used a new `int index = i;` variable to prevent [capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650106/unrolled-loop-works-for-loop-does-not-work/42650142#42650142) the `i` variable and causing it to only download the last image.

```
public GameObject contentRef;
public RawImage imgPrefab;

void Start()
{
    DownloadtheFiles();
}

public void DownloadtheFiles()
{

    List<string> photolist = ES2.LoadList<string>("myPhotos.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < photolist.Count; i++)
    {
        //Don't capture i variable
        int index = i;

        new GetUploadedRequest()

            .SetUploadId(photolist[index])
            .Send((response) =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(DownloadImages(response.Url, index));
            });
    }
}


public IEnumerator DownloadImages(string downloadUrl, int index)
{
    var www = new WWW(downloadUrl);
    yield return www;

    //Instantiate the image prefab GameObject and make it a child of the contentRef
    RawImage newImg = Instantiate(imgPrefab, contentRef.transform);
    //Change the name
    newImg.name = "Image-" + index;

    //Get the downloaded image
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);

    //Apply the downloaded image
    newImg.texture = tex;
}
```

Comment: @Programer The images are shown in a different order each time I enter in the scene. Is it posible that appear always in the same order?

Comment: They should appear in order based on their order in Hierarchy under the  Content Object. Isn't this what's happening now?

Comment: Yes, but this order is different each time I open the scene

Comment: Can you create new post about this? That would be better. Make sure to explain everything required to help you. Post a screenshot of it and in Hierarchy when you loaded the image then another one again after re-opening it. Also explain why you think that a downloaded image that is not saved will be there when you re-start the Editor.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to create a new post. Thank youuu!!