# Unity Coroutine Wait Until true for x seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to implement something that works similar to `yield return new WaitUntil(() => Check());`, but with one extra addition. After the `Check()` condition is met it should wait x seconds checking every frame if the condition is still true.

This is my implementation:

```cs
private IEnumerator CheckCor(float waitTime)
{
    bool checkFlag = true;
    bool checkFlag2;
    float whileTime;
    while (checkFlag)
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => Check());
        checkFlag2 = true;
        whileTime = waitTime;
        while (whileTime > 0)
        {
            if (!Check())
            {
                checkFlag2 = false;
            }
            whileTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
        if (checkFlag2)
        {
            checkFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

where `Check()` is

```cs
private bool Check();
```

My implementation is working perfectly fine, but it seems a bit long.

Is there any shorter way to achieve the same behavior?

(Also making it universal would be a plus e.g. `yield return WaitUntilForSeconds(Check(), 3f);`, where Check() is the condition and 3f is time to check every frame for the condition. I'm guessing it could be done using `CustomYieldInstruction`, but I'm not sure how it works.)

Comment: [`yield return new WaitForSeconds (waitTime);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) ?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear or I don't understand something. How can this help me achieve checking if condition is true for x seconds before proceeding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not too bad to implement this as a `CustomYieldInstruction`. Pass in the checker as a `Func<bool>`, keep a flag to remember if you've started the timer yet or not, and reset that flag if the check function returned false at any point. You can even accept a `Func<float>` to call when the timer is reset with how much time was remaining:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WaitUntilForSeconds: CustomYieldInstruction
{
    float pauseTime;
    float timer;
    bool waitingForFirst;
    Func<bool> myChecker;
    Action<float> onInterrupt;
    bool alwaysTrue;

    public WaitUntilForSeconds(Func<bool> myChecker, float pauseTime, 
            Action<float> onInterrupt = null)
    {
        this.myChecker = myChecker;
        this.pauseTime = pauseTime;
        this.onInterrupt = onInterrupt;

        waitingForFirst = true;
    }

    public override bool keepWaiting
    {
        get
        {
            bool checkThisTurn = myChecker();
            if (waitingForFirst) 
            {
                if (checkThisTurn)
                {
                    waitingForFirst = false;
                    timer = pauseTime;
                    alwaysTrue = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                timer -= Time.deltaTime;

                if (onInterrupt != null && !checkThisTurn && alwaysTrue)
                {
                    onInterrupt(timer);
                }
                alwaysTrue &= checkThisTurn;

                // Alternate version: Interrupt the timer on false, 
                // and restart the wait
                // if (!alwaysTrue || timer <= 0)

                if (timer <= 0)
                {
                    if (alwaysTrue)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        waitingForFirst = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can just use

```
yield return new WaitUntilForSeconds(Check, 3f);

// or

yield return new WaitUntilForSeconds(Check, 3f, (float t) => {Debug.Log($"Interrupted with {t:F3} seconds left!");});
```

And if you need a parameter for the checker, you can use a parameterless lambda:

```
yield return new WaitUntilForSeconds(() => Check(Vector3.up), 3f);
```

And, as usual for lambdas, [be aware of any variable capture you do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650142/1092820).

---

If you don't want an entire `CustomYieldInstruction`, I would just use another `WaitUntil` for the pause:

```
private IEnumerator CheckCor(float waitTime)
{
    bool stillWaiting = true;
    while (stillWaiting)
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => Check());

        float pauseTime = waitTime;
        yield return new WaitUntil(() =>
        {
            pauseTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            stillWaiting = !Check();
            return stillWaiting || pauseTime <= 0;
        });

        if (stillWaiting)
        {
            // Stuff when pause is interrupted goes here
        }
    }

    // Stuff after pause goes here
}
```

Comment: Great answer! The alternate version was the one I wanted. However, I think that there is a slight mistake: `timer` should be used instead of `pauseTime`:  `pauseTime -= Time.deltaTime;` =>  `timer -= Time.deltaTime;` and `if (pauseTime <= 0)` => `if (timer <= 0)`

Comment: Also another example if the parameter is needed in `Check` function: `yield return new WaitUntilForSeconds(() => Check(5), 3f);`

Comment: @sswwqqaa Cool, I fixed that and also added an optional callback for when the timer is interrupted.