# How to make the C++ compiler to follow the same precedence, associativity and order of evaluation that C# has in the this assignment statement?

Tags: c#, c++, evaluation, operator-precedence, associativity

Consider the following piece of code:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
y = x + (x = y);
```

When this runs in C#, the variables end up assigned with these values:

*x = 2*

*y = 3*

On the other hand, when the same runs in C++, the variables end  like this:

*x = 2*

*y = 4*

Clearly, the C++ compiler is using different **precedence**, **associativity** and **order of evaluation** rules than C# (as explained in [this Eric Lippert's article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/)).

So, the question is:

**Is it possible to rewrite the assignment statement to force C++ to evaluate the same as C# does?**

The only restriction is to keep it as a one-liner. I know this can be rewritten by splitting the assignments into two separate lines, but the goal is to maintain it in a single line.

Comment: Out of curiosity is this some kind of assignment you have or requirement, because if it is, it sounds crazy :)

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. Simplest fix is to breakup into 2 lines of code.  See also __what not to ask__: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: Drawing parallels between two unrelated languages might prove counter-productive.

Comment: Why is there this restriction? Is this just out of interest and not a real-world problem?

Comment: @RichardCritten why it is undefined behavior? Expression is evaluated right to left in one case and left to right in the other case, seems pretty defined to me, am I missing something?

Comment: @kuskmen modifying and reading in the same expression.  This changes between C++11 and C++17 but left to right etc has nothing to do with expression evaluation and the freedom the compiler is allowed to optimise.  Complete answer is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Anything can be a one-liner if you use enough semi-colons ;)

Comment: Sure: `x = y; y = x + x;`

Comment: @NathanOliver: doesn't that still result in x=2 & y=4 - OP wanted x=2, y=3

Comment: @PaulF Oh wow, didn't notice that.  I'll have to put my thinking cap on but that doesn't look possible without an extra variable

Comment: Why is the GOAL to "maintain it in a single line"?

Comment: @Peter: Probably because it is a puzzle or challenge, not a real-world engineering problem.

Comment: @Peter (and all other folks that also asked this): Because I am pursuing academic purposes with this exercise. I am trying to achieve an advantageous use of C++ (as language, and resources consumption).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible indeed.

```
x = (y+=x) - x;
```

So simple.

Comment: I want to clarify that I marked this as the accepted answer because it correctly addresses the question being asked and it provides the most optimal solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to rewrite the assignment statement to force C++ to evaluate the same as C# does?

Yes.  To clarify, the rule in C# is that most of the time, the left side of an expression is evaluated fully before the right side.  So C# guarantees that the evaluation of `x` on the left of the `+` happens before the side effect of the `x = y` on the right side.  C++ does not make this guarantee; compilers can disagree as to the meaning of this expression.

(Challenge: I said "most" for a reason. Give an example of a simple expression in C# where a side effect on the left is executed after a side effect on the right.)

> I know this can be rewritten by splitting the assignments into two separate lines

Right. You wish to have a statement that has two side effects: increment y by the original value of x, and assign the original value of y to x.  So you could write that as

```
int t = y;
y = y + x;
x = t;
```

But:

> the goal is to maintain it in a single line.

I assume by "line" you mean "statement". Fine.  Just use the comma operator.

```
int t = ((t = y), (y = y + x), (x = t));
```

Easy peasy.  Why you would want to, I don't know. I assume this is a puzzle designed to elicit signal on whether or not you know about the comma operator.

Extra credit: How many of the parentheses in that statement are required?

---

Super bonus: what if we don't want to use the comma operator?  We can use other operators as sequencing operators.

```
int t = ((t = y) & 0) || ((y = y + x) & 0) || (x = t);
```

We execute the left of the `||`, and it turns out to be false, so we execute the right side, and so on.

Similarly, `((expr1) & 0) ? 0 : (expr2)` guarantees you that `expr1` runs before `expr2`.

Basically what you need here is a guarantee that a number of subexpressions happen in a particular order. Look up "sequence points" to see which operators in C and C++ produce sequence points; you can use them to sequence expressions, hence the name.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Whoops!  Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Not bad but unfortunately you introduced an unused variable warning if you never use `t` (not really a big deal but I always use `-Wall -pedantic`).

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's a strange warning since plainly the variable is both writtten to and read from!

Comment: Huh, I didn't actually read the warning, turns out it was *warning: operation on 't' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]*.  Looks like it might just be a false positive.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well I admit I do not have the C sequence point spec memorized but I was under the impression that comma was a guaranteed sequence operation.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'll try a different version that doesn't use the comma operator.

Comment: The comma operator does introduce a sequence point.  The issue (at least what I think gcc is complaining about) is that `t` isn't actually initialized until the end of the expression.  I would think that `(t = y)` would make it okay.  Only gcc complains so I'm thinking it is just a false positive.

Comment: @NathanOliver: On the one hand, this is probably a false positive for the reasons your describe.  On the other hand, I can't think of any scenario where initializing a variable inside of an assignment to that variable is actually necessary for either performance or readability.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I want to clarify that I upvoted this answer because it provides the best explanation and context-wise references for further learning and exploration of these topics.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
y = std::exchange(x,y) + y;
```

But highly unrecommended. You even have to stop browsing and think about this easy operation.