# Not understanding the line of statement

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
int main()
{
    int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
     m = ++i||++j&&++k;
     printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
     return 0;
}
```

And  output:
-2, 2, 0, 1

But i don't understand the line  `m = ++i||++j&&++k;` How it get's executed.
Someone please explain..Thanks!

Comment: But how m gets increased?

Comment: `||` and `&&` are logical operators. Their result will always be `1` or `0`, depending on whether the expressions evaluate to non-zero or zero values. So you basically have something like: `if ((++i != 0) || (++j != 0) && (++k != 0)) { m = 1; } else { m = 0; }`.

Comment: I hope you are aware that nobody would actually write code like that in a real world program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially you have the 4 variables:

- i = -3
- j = 2
- k = 0
- m is uninitialized

`m = ++i||++j&&++k;` is executed left to right. so first one is `++i` - I suggest reading about the [differences between i++ and ++i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) - In this case `i` is increased by 1 and become i=-2

-2 is a `true` expression, therefore m becomes 1 and the rest of the expression is not evaluated. Because `true or anything else` is always true anyway.
So final outcome:

- i = -2 (increased)
- j = 2 (unchanged)
- k = 0 (unchanged)
- m is 1 (true)

Comment: I will fix. I am used to javascript :)

Answer (score 2):

Logical `OR` operation `(expr1 || expr2)` employs [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior. That is, `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `1` `(true)`.

The expression with logical `OR` operator evaluate to `true` if any of the two operands is non-zero.

In this expression:

```
m = ++i||++j&&++k;
    |_|  |______|
    LHS    RHS
```

The `i` is initialized with `-3`. `++i` will evaluate to `-2`.
`-2` is a non zero value hence evaluate to logical `true` and the RHS part of the expression will not evaluated.

Since the whole expression evaluated to `true`, the value `1` is assigned to `m`.

Comment: you could make the order of evaluation more explicit as `m = (++i) || ((++j) && (++k));`