# ECMAScript Template literals returns different results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ECMAScript 2016. I tried to use template literals to build a simple function to figure tax, but I found when I use different loop styles, the function just returned me completely different results.

When I use `for` loop style:

```
const total = 30
function figureTax(literals) {
  let res = ''
  for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length; ++i) {
    res += literals[i]
    if (i < arguments.length) {
      res += arguments[i]
    }
  }
  // let i = 0
  // while (i < literals.length) {
  //   res += literals[i++]
  //   if (i < arguments.length) {
  //     res += arguments[i]
  //   }
  // }
  return res
}
const res = figureTax`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`
console.log(res)
```

It returned me

> Your tax is (Your tax is (, with tax!) with tax!)4.5

When use `while` style:

```
const total = 30
function figureTax(literals) {
  let res = ''
  // for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length; ++i) {
  //   res += literals[i]
  //   if (i < arguments.length) {
  //     res += arguments[i]
  //   }
  // }
  let i = 0
  while (i < literals.length) {
    res += literals[i++]
    if (i < arguments.length) {
      res += arguments[i]
    }
  }
  return res
}
const res = figureTax`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`
console.log(res)
```

It returned me the correct result:

> Your tax is (4.5 with tax!)

Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with for or while loop. If you use [tag functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) the first argument is an array of the string literals and all the next are the interpolation variables. You use `arguments` which is all of the function's arguments. See below snippet:

```js
const total = 30;

function figureTaxWithFor(literals, ...args) {
  
  let res = '';
  
  for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length; ++i) {
  
    res += literals[i];
  
    if (i < args.length) res += args[i];
  }

  return res;
}

function figureTaxWithWhile(literals, ...args) {
  
  let res = '';
  let i = 0;

  while (i < literals.length) {
    
    res += literals[i++];
  
    if (i - 1 < args.length) res += args[i - 1];
  }

  return res;
}

const res = figureTaxWithFor`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`;
const res2 = figureTaxWithWhile`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`;
console.log(res);
console.log(res2);
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question by changing your code as little as possible, it's because your while loop increments `i` before accessing `arguments`, but your for loop was *not* doing so. If you rewrite the for loop as follows, it also works:

```js
const total = 30
function figureTax(literals) {
  let res = ''
  for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length;) {
    res += literals[i++]
    if (i < arguments.length) {
      res += arguments[i]
    }
  }
  return res
}
const res = figureTax`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

the difference comes from where you're incrementing `i` in your while loop:

```
res += literals[i++]
```

for your first iteration, this would return `literals[0]`, but it would compare `1 < arguments.length` and add `arguments[1]`.

however, in your for loop, you're incrementing via `++i`:

```
for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length; ++i) {
```

for your first iteration, this would return `literals[**1**]` and it would compare `1 < arguments.length` and add `arguments[1]`.

to fix the for loop, change to `i++` and add `+ 1` where necessary:

```js
const total = 30

function figureTax(literals) {
  let res = ''

  for ( let i = 0; i < literals.length; i++) {
    res += literals[i]

    if ((i + 1) < arguments.length) {
      res += arguments[i + 1]
    }
  }

  return res
}

const res = figureTax`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`
console.log(res)
//Your tax is (4.5 with tax!)
```

for more information, see [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to take the same index for `literals` as for `arguments` and while `arguments[0]` is equal to `literals`, you get the same content too.

To overcome this, you could take a rest syntax

```
figureTax(literals, ...params)
```

and catch all paramters and loop with the same index. This has the roblem of the last parameter as your approach.

---

Why not simplify the loop to a check of literals and arguments which have the same length.

```js
function figureTax(literals) {
    let res = literals[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < literals.length; ++i) {
        res += arguments[i] + literals[i];
    }
    return res;
}

const total = 30
const res = figureTax`Your tax is (${ total * 0.15 } with tax!)`

console.log(res)
console.log(figureTax``);
```