# printf treats *p++ differently from what happens to p

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf

*p++ in general adds 1 to pointer then references.
But printf is taking the value after just dereferencing while the pointer got increased then dereferenced.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 10,20,30 };
    int *p = a;

    printf("%d\n", *p++);//this makes p point at 20 but prints 10
    printf("%d\n", *p);//prints 20
    printf("%d\n", a[0]);//prints 10

}
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `*p++` is a post-fix increment. Although `p` is incremented `*p` reflects the contents of `p` before increment. [Built-in postfix operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_postfix_operators)

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i

Comment: thank you very much I got it !

Answer (score 6):

> *p++ in general adds 1 to pointer then [de]references

[No it doesn't.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24853/560648)

You used *postfix* increment (the `++` is after the `p`) so the original value is provided, not the newly incremented value.

You're thinking of `*++p`.

Comment: I know that you state in your profile "Don't write answers in comments." - Hence my immediate upvote... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff And hence I did not upvote your answer-in-comments ;)