# What's the difference between --i and i - 1 in a parameter in C?

Tags: c++, c, recursion, operators, parameter-passing

I'm writing a program that prints out the first 10 natural numbers in recursion. First off, I'm putting a parameter "--num"

```c
int natural_numbers(int num) {
    if (num > 1) // Base case
        natural_numbers(--num);
    printf("%d ", num);
}
```

```
Input: 10
Output: 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And then I changed the parameter to "num - 1" and it prints out what I was expected.

```c
int natural_numbers(int num) {
    if (num > 1) // Base case
        natural_numbers(num - 1);
    printf("%d ", num);
}
```

```
Input: 10
Output: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I have no idea why the first one ouput was wrong. I need some help.

Comment: `--num` decrements `num` by 1, and then you print that number out on the next line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: So is this C or c++

Comment: Jack, didn't you accept one of the answers previously (@Bartek's if I'm not mistaken)? What made you change your mind to reopen this question?

Answer (score 1):

`num - 1` creates a new temporary `int`, as a copy of `num`, and subtracts 1 from that temporary `int`.

`--num` subtracts 1 from `num` itself.

Also, note that your function `natural_numbers` should be `void`. It now says `int` but you don't return anything so your program really has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You could use a debugger and step through your program to see when things go bad, or add some debugging prints. This is your original program with prints *before* and *after* the recursive call. The number before and after should be the same for the algorithm to work, and as you will see, they are not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void natural_numbers(int num) {
    static size_t indent = 0;
    std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << "num before: " << num << "\n";
    if(num > 1) { // Base case
        ++indent;
        natural_numbers(--num);
        --indent;
    }
    std::cout << std::string(indent, ' ') << "num after: " << num << "\n";
}

int main() {
    natural_numbers(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but why it prints number 1 twice and missing number 10?

Comment: Since you change num before you print it, 10 can't be printed (if 10 is your original input number). 1 is printed for the same reason. When num==2 you change num and call natural_numbers which willl print 1, and when the call returns, you print 1 again.

Answer (score 1):

In first part you change num value with pre-decrement `--` operator. Your second code doesn't change num value (it pass temporary `num - 1` value to function call).

So if you next `printf` `num` value it is different. In first code part it is decrement by one, and in second part it is original `num` value.

If you originaly call `natural_numbers` with `num == 10`, below you can track how its value change/not change in next lines.

```cpp
                                  //      num (its value)
int natural_numbers(int num) {    //       10
    if (num > 1) // Base case     //       10
        natural_numbers(--num);   //       10 / and 9 (after execution)
    printf("%d ", num);           //        9
}

int natural_numbers(int num) {    //       10
    if (num > 1) // Base case     //       10
        natural_numbers(num - 1); //       10
    printf("%d ", num);           //       10
}
```

Comment: Ohh, so that's why. Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `num - 1` to a function (as in fact you do here), the way to do that is to simply call `natural_numbers(num - 1)`.  Nothing fancy needed.  It's no coincidence that's the way that works.

C's special `++` and `--` operators do more -- significantly more -- than just add or subtract 1.  They add or subtract 1, *and they store the incremented or decremented variable back into the original location*.  So `--num` doesn't just subtract 1 from `num`, it stores the value `num - 1` back into `num`.  But that's not what you want here.  You don't want to modify `num`, because on each recursive call, you want to print out the value of `num` you started with, *not* the decremented version you passed down into the recursion.

Answer (score -1):

You think we would want to call that function by num 3

when you use --num its just like you are changing that entered number in the natural_function so

the local stack when natural_numbers(3) called is look like

```
// =========call natural_number(3)

natural_number(2) // --num (change num itself. its like num = num - 1 then pass it)

// But here in this local stack  block "num" becomes 2 

print 2 // <== here it prints 2 on the backward step

// ========= call natural_number(2)

natural_number(1) // --num (change num itself. its like num = num - 1 then pass it)

// But here in this local stack  block "num" becomes 1

print 1 // <== Here it prints 1 on the backward step

// ========= call natural_number(1)

print 1 // Here we go out of stack by printing 1  

Result: 1 1 2
```

---

Now if we would call that function with (num - 1)
it means you dont want to change the "num" variable entering in own local stack block.

The local stack for (num - 1) will be like this:

```
// ========= call natural_number(3)

natural_number(2) // (num - 1) (num wont change. its like temp = num - 1 then pass temp to it)

print 3 // Here it prints 3 on the backward step

// ========= call natural_number(2)

natural_number(1) // (num - 1) (num wont change. its like temp = num - 1 then pass temp to it)

print 2 // <== Here it prints 2 on the backward step

// ========= call natural_number(1)

print 1 // Here we go out of stack by returning 1  

Result: 1 2 3
```