# I'm confused about the output

Tags: c, input, output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int a , b ,c ;
  printf("Enter values for a and b: ");
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    a = a + b-- ;

  if (a<b){
    c = -1;
  printf("\n\t%d %d %d\n\n",a,b,c);
          }
  else {
    c = 0;
    printf("\n\t%d %d %d\n\n",a,b,c);
       }
}
```

Lets assume the value of the input for a and b are 2 (for both of them).
I studied the above program, but when it comes to the output it will be 4 1 0, a=4,b=1,c=0.
But, the calculation part above said that a=a+b-1 which will be the value of a is 3, now the new value of a is 3. But for b the value is still 2 because we didn't assign a new value to it.

I am very confused about the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `a+1`, `a++` and `++a`. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858/6625422).
Therefore, when you say

```c
a = a + b--;
```

You are actually saying

```c
a = a + b;
b = b - 1;
```

If you say

```c
a = a + --b;
```

It becomes

```c
b = b - 1;
a = a + b;
```

And if you say

```c
a = a + (b-1)
```

It does what you think: `a = a + b - 1`. The value of `b` doesn't change afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, a and b are both 2

Then, you execute `a = a + b--;`.

The decrement operator is located after the `b`, so it evaluates to:

```
a=a+b;
b=b-1;
```

After this, a will be 4 and b will be 1.

a is not smaller than b, so c will be 0.

​

Note:

If it would be `a = a + --b`, it would evaluate to

```
b=b-1;
a=a+b;
```

Because the `--` is executed at the beginning of the evaluation.

Comment: That means the decrement operator will work after the calculation part and then it will decrease the value of b...

Comment: That's made me very confusing Woow,, I appreciate your explanation. Thank you

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would appreciate if you accept it.

Comment: @Hamoud: Please read about the pre- and post-increment operators.