# How does the increment operator work with an array?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, operators, increment

In the code below: how does the increment operator(++) work? Is it increasing the value of the array or iterating through the array somehow?

```
  scanf("%d",&e);
  for(i=0;i<e;i++)
  {
   scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
   graph[x][0]++;
   graph[x][graph[x][0]]=y;
   graph[y][0]++;
   graph[y][graph[y][0]]=x;
  }
```

Comment: Presumably `graph[x][0]` contains some value of a type that supports the increment operator. Maybe an int? Without seeing the definition of `graph` it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: Unrelated: I recommend sanitizing `x` and `y` before using them as array indices. The foolish or malicious user can cause a great deal of harm if you don't make absolutely certain what they've provided is in range. In general, always make sure you A) got input (check `scanf`'s return code as it may have failed) and B) the value of the input is in a range you can use.

Comment: Is this code from a crackme or similar?

Answer (score 4):

`++` is a *unary* operator, i.e., it acts on one operand.

The statement `graph[x][0]++;` should be perceived as `(graph[x][0])++;`, which means that the value in the 2d array `graph` at index `x` and `0` for the first and the second dimension respectively is fetched, and then the operator is applied to it, thus increasing it by one.

> Is it increasing the value of the array

Yes, at a specific index.

> or iterating through the array somehow?

No.

Answer (score 0):

Let´s first see how the increment-operator `++` usually works:

```
var++
```

The increment operator is used to increase a value held and portrayed by a variable by `1` or `1.0`, equivalent to the statement `var = var + 1;` or `var = var + 1.0;`.

So it is increasing the value by 1 counter.

Now lets look on what an array is:

```
datatype array_of_variables[index];
```

An array is a bond of several variables of the same datatype. By giving the index fields we can access certain variables of this cluster.

```
array_of_variables[0];
```

Following the above statement, we access the variable which is at first in dimension 1, due to of course, this is an one-dimensional array only.

So, the expression `array_of_variables[0]` is an identification for this first variable and the value held inside it.

The same goes for two-dimensional arrays. The only thing what is changed is that the "adressing" of a certain variable is now done by two index fields, according to the where the variable is stored in the dimensions.

So, `array_of_variables[0][1]` equals the value held by variable 2 in dimension 1. It is an identification for it.

---

Now the statement,

```
 array_of_variables[0][1]++;
```

does the same as done by a certain variable on its own. It is increasing the value inside the corresponding variable.

The array as whole does not get changed. Only a specific variable and the its value.

---

There is also an important difference whether the operator is preceding the variable `++var` or trailing at it `var++`.

But I do not want to discuss that certain topic here further, it is best explained at:
[C: What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The `++` and `--` operators act on scalar values, incrementing or decrementing them.  An array (not a pointer) is an aggregate of values (an ordered list of values stored contiguously in memory) so it cannot be *incremented* or *decremented*.

What is confusing about this is that an array and a pointer share access methods when the `[]` operator is used, as the pointer is considered a scalar value and is allowed to be *incremented* or *decremented*.

So you can increment or decrement a pointer, when you do this, the pointer will point to the *next* (or *previous*) element, considering the elements are stored in *array style*.  This is a very useful C tool, that allows to position a pointer just pointing to an *array element* (never confuse an array element with the whole array) and move it forward or backward, by incrementing or decrementing the pointer.

But remember, an array and a pointer are different things.  An array is an aggregate of elements, while a pointer is an object that stores the address of another.

In the case you post, the postincrement operator is attached to `graph[x][0]` which represents an array element (a single cell) so it is incrementing the array element positioned at position `[x][0]`, and not the whole array.

Arrays are very simple in what operations they allow the programmer, the only operations they allow are

- To use the name of the array, which represents a fixed, constant, pointer *value* (not object) that points to the address of it first element in the array,
- and applying it the `sizeof` operator, that will give you the actual size of the array.

No more operations are permitted on arrays.  If you try to increment or decrement this pointer, as in `graph++` (or `++graph`) you'll get an error, noticing you about the fact that an array is not a pointer object, or if you take the `sizeof` operator to an array, you'll get the full size of the array in bytes, while if you do this to a pointer, you'll get the size of the pointer variable, different things (normally, all pointers are the same size in a fixed architecture, but array sizes normally depend on the number of elements declared).

The `[]` operator is defined for pointers, and there's a trick here, to mean the same as the following equivalent expressions: `a[b]` is equivalent to the expresion `*(a + b)` for pointers, as you normally use the name of the array, it means to add `b` to the pointer to the first element (to move the `a` pointer value `b` element places up in memory), and then access the *pointed to* value.