# How does incrementing an element(integer) in array work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

```
int main(){
    int a[5]= {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
    int i, j, k=1, m;
    i = ++a[1]; // i becomes a[1] + 1 which is 2 but a[1] changes to 2 even though I'm assigning a value to i?
    j = a[1]++; // j becomes a[1]+1 which is 2+1 but stay as 2? 
    m = a[i++]; // because i is 2, shouldn't the output be a[3]? 

    printf("\n%d %d %d", i, j, m);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the output comes out as 3, 2, 15.

How does the increments work specifically? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pre-increment operator (`++x`) increments the value and returns *the new value*. The post-increment operator (`x++`) increments the value and returns *the old value*.

It's easy to see what happens if you decompose the pre-increment and post-increment operators into two different lines.

```
int a[5]= {5, 1, 15, 20, 25};
int i, j, k=1, m;

// i = ++a[1]; becomes:
++a[1];    // a = {5, 2, 15, 20, 25}
i = a[1];  // i = 2

// j = a[1]++; becomes:
j = a[1];  // j = 2
a[1]++;    // a = {5, 3, 15, 20, 25}

// m = a[i++]; becomes:
m = a[i];  // m = a[2] = 15
i++;       // i = 3
```

So, in the end:

```
i = 3
j = 2
m = 15
```

---

In particular, in this case:

```
m = a[i++];
```

The variable `i` previously had a value of `2`, so the *post*-increment operator increments `i` (which becomes `3`), but *returns `2`*, so that line is equivalent to:

```
m = a[i];  // Use old value here
i++;       // Increment after
```

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much for the help! How can a[i++]  be broken down to m =a[i] and i++ ? I'm a newbie to coding sorry if it's a stupid question lol

Comment: @AlexOh added a more detailed explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

```
i = ++a[1];
```

> //i becomes a[1] + 1 which is 2 but a[1] changes to 2 even though i am assigning a value to i?

Correct, `i` becomes the value of `a[1] + 1` and `a[1]` do so too. Both, `a[1]` and `j` have the value of `2` after the expression.

---

#### 2.

```
j = a[1]++;
```

> // j becomes a[1]+1 which is 2+1 but stay as 2?

No, `j` do not get to the value evaluated by `a[1] + 1`.

After this expression, The value inside of `j` is still `a[1]` or better said `2`, but the value of `a[i]` will change to `3` after the expression.

The Postincrement-Operator `(variable)++`, as opposed to the Preincrement-Operator, `++(variable)`, increases the value of the operand only **after** the respective operation:

[C: What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

---

#### 3.

```
m = a[i++];
```

> // because i is 2, shouldn't the output be a[3]?

No, because like I said above, The Postincrement-Operator only increments the value of the operand after the operation, so `i` in `m = a[i++];` is still `i`, not `i + 1`.

Comment: Actually, Robert, that's not right.  `a[1]` *does* get incremented, regardless.  But, because this is a *pre-*increment case, you get the *incremented* value.  Post-increment would have returned the value before it got incremented.

Answer (score 1):

*Pre-increment* first increments the value, then returns the incremented value to you.  *Post-increment* returns the value before it gets incremented.

The first statement *initially* sets `i=2,` but the third statement `i++` increments it again.  That's why `i=3` in the result.  `j=2` because at the time this was the value of `a[1]`.  `m=15` because at the time the statement is executed, `i=2` and this is the *(zero-based)* value of that element in the array.

The code as written does many things which are difficult to decipher ... hence the question.  It's not a good idea to write code in this way except as an exercise.