# The evaluation of logical expressions containing incrementation in C

Tags: c, increment, logical-operators, evaluation

I just wrote a little program to help me get familiar with logical expression in C, and I was expecting the result to be:

```
1 
1 1 1
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 

{

    int I = 1, J = 1, K = 1;
    printf("%d\n", ++I || ++J && ++K);
    printf("%d %d %d", I, J ,K);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead, I got:

```
1 
2 1 1
```

The value of `I` was incremented by 1, and I have no idea why.

As far I have learned, `I` wasn't assigned(`=`) any new value in my program, so how was it value be changed?

Comment: `++I` increments `I`. Note that `&&` has greater precendence than `||` so the expression is evaluated as `++I || (++J && ++K)`. But because of the short-circuit rule, only the `++I` is evaluated and the expression must be `true` without needing to evaluate further. Beware of side-effects!

Comment: @Weather Vane I thought that ```++J && ++K``` was evaluated first since && has higher precedence than || and the values of both of them had been incremented, apparently I was wrong

Comment: It is evaluated from left to right, subject to precedence. The precedence means the expression is evaluated as `++I || (++J && ++K)` and not as `(++I || ++J) && ++K`

Comment: @Mattmmmmm: precedence only affects grouping of operators and operands, it does not control order of evaluation.  Both `&&` and `||` force left-to-right evaluation.

Comment: The statements `I++;` and `I = I + 1;` have the exact same effect (incrementing `I`) but the sub-expressions have different values (assuming `I` has value `42` before the expression, the `I++` evaluates to `42`; `I = I + 1` evaluates to `43`).

Answer (score 5):

Your question addresses two separate issues.

The first one: Why is `I` incremented?

The second one: If the output is `2 1 1` and `I` was incremented why aren´t `J` and `K` incremented then too?

---

#### 1.

> Why is `I` incremented?

`++` is the increment operator. It increments an operand by `1` count, analogous to the expressions `i = i + 1` or `i += 1`, where `i` stands for the operand.

There is a difference between set `++` in front of (`++i`) or behind (`i++`) an operand. The answers under the following linked question address the difference at its best, so I won´t go too much in detail about this topic here since the difference is not crucial important at your provided code and I just wanted to annotate that circumstance for that you use the increment operator in your future programs properly and avoid further confusions.

[C: What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/c-what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Back to your code.

Since you use:

```
printf("%d\n", ++I || ++J && ++K);
```

`I` is immediately incremented by `1` inside the expression, so its value is actually `2`, although this does not influence the logical evaluation because any value which is non-zero would be evaluated as `1`/`true` as result of a logical condition test.

That´s why

```
printf("%d %d %d", I, J ,K);
```

prints `2` as the value of `I`.

---

#### 2.

> Why aren´t `J` and `K` incremented then too?

Logical testing evaluates from left to right. `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`. `&&` combined expressions/sub-conditions need to be fulfilled together to be evaluated as `true` condition. As soon as a condition becomes `true`, which is the case with `++I`, the evaluation of the remaining conditions is omitted since it is redundant.

That´s why `J` and `K` aren´t incremented by `1` with:

```
printf("%d\n", ++I || ++J && ++K);
```

but `I` is.

Thus, the correct output of

```
printf("%d %d %d", I, J ,K);
```

is:

```
2 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the expression

```
printf("%d\n", ++I || ++J && ++K);
```

`++I || ++J && ++K` is a logical expression, yes, but it's also incrementing all you variables, so they all should be `2` in the end of the expression and your output should be:

```
1 // true expression, I, J and K are all positive values
2 2 2
```

So why does this not happen?

Well, since `I = 1`, no more evaluations are needed, because the compiler knows that `1 || 0 && 0` is `1`, (note that the evaluation is left to right and `&&` has precedence over `||`) this is the reason why `++J` and `++K` are not evaluated, and thus not incremented.

So, in the second `printf` you will have `I = 2`, `J = 1` and `K = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `++I` evaluates the current value of `I` *plus `1`*; as a *side effect*, `I` is incremented.

Due to operator precedence rules, the expression `++I || ++J && ++K` is parsed as `++I || (++J && ++K)`.  Both `||` and `&&` force left-to-right evaluation, so `++I` is evaluated first.

Both `||` and `&&` short-circuit - if the left-hand operand of `++I || ++J && ++K` (`++I`) is non-zero, then the result of the expression is true (`1`) regardless of the value of the right-hand operand (`++J && ++K`), so the right hand operand isn’t evaluated at all.

If `I` starts out as `-1`, then `++I` would evaluate to `0` (false) and then `++J && ++K` would be evaluated. If the left-hand operand `++J` evaluates to `0` (false), then the result of the expression is false regardless of the result of `++K`, so `++K` won’t be evaluated.