# Why is the output "false2", when the condition at the if block is 1 which is true?

Tags: c

Why is the output "false2", when the condition at the if block is 1 which is true ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int x=0;
if (x++)
printf("true1");
else if (x==1)
printf("false2");
return 0;}
```

Comment: if condition first evaluate x that is 0 then ++ it. use ++x instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x++` means first use the value of `x` and then increment it's value by 1. So your if condition is `if(0)`, Then `x` value increments and becomes 1. So your else if condition is `else if(1)`. Whereas `++x` means first increase the value of `x` by 1 and then use it so your first condition is `if(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

> when the condition at the if block is 1 which is true ?

That's not the case. The `if` condition is actually false.

The expression `x++` yields the current value of `x` (which is what's used to test the condition) and then increments it. Since `x`'s current value is `0`, it evaluates to false and thus it goes into the `else if` condition.

Contrast this with `++x` which increments first and then yields the new value.

See [C: What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24853/4389800)

Answer (score 0):

The first time `x` is tested, it is zero *and then* it is incremented:

```
//x is post-incremented, i.e. evaluated before being incremented
int x=0;
if (x++)//x is tested when x==0, then is incremented
printf("true1");
else if (x==1)//execution flow goes here...
printf("false2");//...then here
```

To make `x` test as TRUE on the first iteration change it to a pre-increment:

```
//x is pre-incremented, i.e. incremented before being evaluated
int x=0;
if (++x)//x is incremented, then tested when x==1
printf("true1");//execution flow goes here...
else if (x==1)
printf("false2");
//...then here
```