# how to increment the index at each call when pressing the same button?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexing, increment

i know this is sth really easy to do for many of you, but i have been trying all the answers here and everywhere else... none of them worked ..to me.. maybe you can help with this..?
i have an ArrayList (keys) ... and i want to increment the index at each call... with a button..
i want the first out put to be:     "key" : 0, then, pressing the button again and:"key" : 1, and again "key" : 2.  Thank you in advance!!
I did this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    if (like) {
        Log.i("key", keys.get(i));
        keys.set(i, keys.get(i) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `like`? maybe that condition cause to prevent from increasing value

Comment: i thought of it too ..   0,1,2,3,4,5 ... i know ints are immutable..thats why im trying to replace the value, but i dont know if i should crate a variable and then, replace it into the keys.get(i)+  "the new variable"----
thanks for replying Mustafa.. im very new at all this..thank you!

Comment: so does your problem has been solved?

Comment: not yet @MustafaPoya im trying everything here :)

Comment: try to add the code of the `button` in your question for better help

Comment: i will @MustafaPoya but.......
 its just :

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       

nothing weird..tho

Comment: Does Log.i("key", keys.get(i)); add logs. How are you verifying or debugging whether your code worked correctly or not. I think you are debugging with the Log.i("key", keys.get(i)); whether the code executed correctly or not then it is completely false because this is executing before to the increment step. Please look into this.

Comment: @sarathchandra dont get pissed with me.. im new in all this.. im here to learn more, i wasnt born knowing, i will follow your recommendations, thank you!

Comment: @JonathanCheli I am just asking how are you verifying that's it. just write a System.out.println(keys.get(i)); after keys.set(i, keys.get(i) + 1); and paste the output. I think it will get incremented

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a global variable for index and then try to log and set the value in keys in click listener. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
int index = 0;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    Log.i("key: ", index);
    index++;
    keys.set(i, index);
});
```

Comment: @MustafaPoya SE uses something called "caching", which means it's perfectly possible to miss answers being posted. Accusing people of plagiarism on an answer that's under a minute apart is not okay. On new questions, identical answers can often show up right after each other. That doesn't mean this was copied.

Answer (score 0):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    if (like) {
        Log.i("key", keys.get(i));
        int temp = keys.get(i);
        ++temp;
        keys.set(i, temp);
    }
}
```

or

```java
for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
    if (like) {
        Log.i("key", keys.get(i));
        keys.set(i, (keys.get(i)) + 1);
    }
}
```

any of the above 2 code snippets should solve your problem and even your code snippet is correct. can you please share more info about how you are verifying.

Answer (score -1):

```
Log.i("key", keys.get(i++));
```

should do the trick

Comment: Ill give it a try and ill let you know.. Indycate  :)

Comment: and no...not happening.. im still getting 0... i dont get it 

Comment: @JonathanCheli See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858 - also note that this answer doesn't work, as it increments the key instead of the value. At about keys.size() / 2, this will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Also, AFAIK, Java doesn't let you use prefix or postfix `++` on maps, arrays, lists, sets, or other similar constructs

Comment: @Zoe super cool post, yes it did increment the key but not the value..as u mentioned.. thank so much for this post :)