# Finding whether an input contains a vowel

Tags: c

The sample input contains: 3, omahgoToRuLob, OmAhgotUrulobEI, aYfun
The expected output is: ugly string
pretty string
pretty string

I received an error such as:
22:7: error: array size missing in ‘string’
27:23: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token
29:14: error: expected expression before ‘]’ token

My code is in c programming.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    char string[100];
    char vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"};

    for (i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%99s", string[]);

        if (string[] == vowels) 
            printf("lovely string \n");
        else
            printf("ugly string \n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `char string[];` --> `char string[100];` and `scanf("%s", &string[]);` --> `scanf("%99s", string);`. `string[] == vowels` --> research `strspn()`

Comment: I have edited my code like u suggest but i still received the same error.

Comment: The subscript operator `[]` is used to denote that the programmer desires to access the i-th index of an array. So, the compiler expects an index value (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc.) before `]` token.

Comment: @Chewjunnie Looks like you skipped on researching `strspn()`.

Comment: i did researched on strspn(), but how can i use it on my code? It doesnt have a bool, thus i cant used T/F function to print the respective function

Comment: It's hard to help you because almost none of this makes sense. Which is to say, I can't tell you how to fix what you wrote because I can't tell what you expect your code to mean. For example, where you have `if (string[] == vowels)`, what exactly do you expect to be compared to what? You do understand that `[]` is *not part of the variable name*, right? And if you want to know whether a vowel is *in* some string, how does it help you to check whether the string *is equal to* something?

Comment: i want to compare whether the sample input contains a vowel

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't declare an array without defining the array size, unless you do it dynamically
2. You declare one char, but you assign all the vowels to this char.

   - `char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};`
3. `scanf("%s", string);` is the right way to use scanf() with strings. Also, you want this out of your for loop, because you just get the input once
4. You have a variable `i` in your loop that you don't use. Also, you have `i<4` while the input might be larger
5. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24858/15462790) about i++ and ++i
6. Also you have to compare each char of the input string with each char of the vowels array
7. You don't need to store both lowercase and uppercase vowels. Use the `tolower(char c)` function from `ctype.h` to convert the input characters to lowercase and compare them only to lowercase vowels.