# In C or C++, is there a way to get the address of i++ or ++i ("i" is int type)?

Tags: c++, c

Is there a way to write something like below:

```c
int i = 0;
int *p1 = &(i++);
int *p2 = &(++i);
```

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: First of all please never use the term "C/C++". There is no such single language, only the two separate, distinct and very different languages C and C++. Secondly you can't get the address of an expression or an *rvalue*. The main distinction between lvalue and rvalues is that the address can be taken of an lvalue (using the address-of or pointer-to operator `&`) but not of an rvalue.

Comment: No to the 1st and yes to the 2nd - live - https://godbolt.org/z/PW4vYa8Mf

Comment: And as @πάνταῥεῖ writes, why would you need that? What's the underlying problem you're supposed to solve, and why do you think using the address-of operator `&` would solve that problem?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different rules. Choose only one

Comment: I don't understand.  The location of `i` is the same regardless of whether it is incremented (pre or post), divided, multiplied or otherwise value changed.  The increment operators change the content of the variable, not its location.  Also, be aware that asking for the address of the variable prevents the variable from being in a register (since registers don't have addressable locations on most processors).

Comment: Related: *[What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/)*

Answer (score 7):

Before asking "Is there a way", I think we have to ask, "What would it mean?"

In C, we have the concept of "object" versus "value".  Basically, an object is a thing that can hold a value.  So a variable like

```
int a;
```

is clearly an object, because it can hold a value — that is, we can say things like

```
a = 5;
```

to store a value into `a`.

The key distinction between an object and a value is that an object has a *location*.  A value, on the other hand, is something we've computed that's just kind of floating in space, and if we don't find an object to store it in pretty soon, it disappears.

(Side note: You will sometimes come across the terms "lvalue" and "rvalue", which mean the same thing as "object" and "value" as I've been using them here.  An lvalue is something that can appear on the left side of an assignment operator, while an rvalue is something that can only appear on the right.)

I've gone through this longish background introduction just so I can make this important point: *You can only apply the address-of operator to an object, because only objects have locations.*  It makes perfect sense to say

```
int *p = &a;
```

But it would make no sense to say

```
int *p2 = &5;            /* WRONG */
```

or

```
int *p3 = &(1 + 2);      /* WRONG */
```

So it would equally make no sense to write

```
int *p4 = &(a + 1);      /* WRONG */
```

The variable `a` is an object, but the thing that you get by fetching `a`'s value and adding 1 to it is clearly just a value.  By the time we've computed that value, it doesn't really matter (we might as well have forgotten) that one part of the computation of that value involved fetching a value from the object `a`.

But then we get you your questions.  Suppose you try to write

```
int *p5 = &(i++);        /* questionable */
int *p6 = &(++i);
```

The `++` operator takes a value and adds 1 to it, and the value `i + 1` is clearly just a value, without a location.  But, its true, `i++` and `++i` mean more than just "`i + 1`" — they compute the value `i + 1` *and store it back into `i`*.  So you can almost convince yourself that `i++` and `++i` have locations — but if they did, it would just be the location of the variable `i`.  So you might as well have just said

```
int *p7 = &i;
```

Now, you might ask, "But what if I want to take the address of `i`, at the same time I increment it?"  And the answer is, you're just going to have to do it in two steps:

```
int *p7 = &i;
i++;
```

Yes, it's true, the `i++` and `++i` operators are nice in that they let you do two things at once, things like

```
int x = array[i++];
```

or

```
int x = *p++;
```

But those are useful operations, because they come up all the time when you're working with arrays.  But the need to say something like

```
int *p5 = &(i++);
```

comes up much less often, I think, so it's not nearly so important to have it work.  (Me, I've been programming in C for 40 years, and I don't think I've ever felt the need to grab a pointer to `i` and increment it at the same time.)  The `++` operator is something that often comes up in a loop, as `i` moves through an array or something.  But since the address of `i` doesn't change, if you need a pointer to it, It makes sense to do that just once, before the loop (or whatever) even starts.

Finally, whether you agree with my explanations so far or not, the C Standard explicitly says that the result of the `++` and `--` operators is an rvalue, not an lvalue.  Two compilers I just tried this on gave me the errors

```
error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int'
```

and

```
error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
```

and these error messages pretty much say the same story I've been telling.

Although, to throw a pretty big monkey wrench into this story I've been telling, the rules are evidently different in C++!  You can't do `&(i++)`, but you *can* do `&(++i)`!  I think there's a good reason for this, but I don't remember what it is.

Comment: *the `i++` and `++i` operators are nice in that they let you do two things at once*  Which just increases the difficulty of understanding what the code is does.  And that's not a good thing because it leads to hard-to-diagnose bugs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's perfectly fine, I think, as long as the "two things" are inseparably related, as in `a[i++]` and `*p++`.  Otherwise, yes, autoincrement can be abused as badly as `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, the statement

```
int *p1 = &(i++);
```

will not work as `i++` returns an rvalue and you cannot take the address of an `rvalue`.

On the other hand, the statement

```
int *p2 = &(++i);
```

is fine (i.e., it works). Check it out [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zcjLu8yjvs9JwsU8).

Comment: "`int *p2 = &(++i);` is fine" ... I haven't checked, the compiler may accept it, but that statement is most definitely not _fine_ from the perspective of anyone who needs to read and grok that code.

Comment: Can you explain why isn't it fine ? Or what exactly is the problem in writing `int *p2 = &(++i);` .

Comment: I think you need to convince fellow developers that packing many distinct operations in the space of a single line is a "_fine_" thing to do. That is, the burden lies with you. You are writing for other humans, not the compiler.

Comment: By fine i mean it works in C++ and nothing else. The question was about "whether there is a way to write" and not about how the code looks.

Comment: The other part of the question of whether it is/isn't fine is when/why you would ever write it in a real program.  The code `int i = j++ + ++k - m-- - --n;` is equally "fine", but equally meaningless.

Comment: @SteveSummit The question's title reads "Is there a way to get address of i++ or ++i (i is int type)" and so my answer is specifically focused  on answering this very question.

Answer (score 1):

I already know the question with this answer and apologize for the initial unclear question.

In C, we cannot use `&(i++)` and `&(++i)` and I think the reason is `i++` and `++i` are rvalues in C. However in C++, `i++` is rvalue and `++i` is lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

`i++` yields the value of `i` before being incremented and increments it.

If `&(i++)` were valid, it would mean take the address of the "previous value". Since `i` is the name we are using for a single memory location, where would that previous value go?

If you need the previous value of `i`, it needs to be stored somewhere before you can do anything with it including pointing to it.

```
int j = i++;
int *ip = &i;
int *jp = &j;
```

Then, `*ip` will yield the incremented value and `*jp` will yield the value before the increment.

Since `++i` yields the incremented value of `i`, it works with just a single value. Still, for clarity, best to use separate statements for the increment and taking the address of the variable:

```
int *ip = &i;
++i;
```

even if the compiler allows `&(++i)` or even if it is legal (did not check). You are writing for the fellow programmer (who might be you), not the compiler.