# Recursive function, where the argument is passed in the different ways

Tags: c, function, recursion, arguments, decrement

Could someone please explain to me the difference between these three blocks of code?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a)
{
    printf("%d", a);

    if (a >= 1)
        f(--a);

    printf("%d", a);
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 32100012

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a)
{
    printf("%d", a);

    if (a >= 1)
        f(a - 1);

    printf("%d", a);
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 32100123

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int a)
{
    printf("%d", a);

    if (a >= 1)
        f(a--);

    printf("%d", a);
}

int main()
{
    f(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: Infinite printing of the number 3

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were calling `main` from inside another function.

Comment: So you're asking what pre-decrement and post-decrement do? This is well documented already.

Comment: Follow the control flow by pen and paper, and you will see. If you're brave, you can use your debugger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Answer (score 1):

```
    1) printf("%d", a); if (a >= 1) f(--a); printf("%d", a);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ******************* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        *********** f(2) **
```

print `a` twice with something in between; something includes decrementing `a`. So `f(3)` prints `3<something_recursive_from_f(2)>2`

```
    2) printf("%d", a); if (a >= 1) f(a - 1); printf("%d", a);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ********************* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        *********** f(2) ****
```

print `a` twice with something in between. So `f(3)` prints `3<something_recursive_from_f(2)>3`

```
    3) printf("%d", a); if (a >= 1) f(a--); printf("%d", a);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ******************* ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        *********** f(3) **
```

print `a` twice with something in between; something includes decrementing `a`. So `f(3)` prints `3<something_recursive_from_f(3)>2`
... **but** something recursive is `f(3)` again... and `f(3)` again... and `f(3)` again... till your computer burns out.

Answer (score 1):

Third one `f(a--);` it is always calling `f` with the `a == 3`, then (after the function return) it will subtract `1` from `a`. But will never happen.

The second one - it simply calls the `f` with `a minus 1` but not changing the `a` printing everything from 3 to 0 and then when the function returns the second print prints it in the reverse order as functions return in the FIFO basis.

The first one is basically very similar to the second one but `a` is decremented thus result printed by the second `printf` are `0012` not `0123`

Answer (score 1):

Some visual aids.

Consider what happens in the first code sample:

```
f(3)
-> prints "3"
-> decrements a to 2
-> calls f(2)
   -> prints "2"
   -> decrements a to 1
   -> calls f(1)
      -> prints "1"
      -> decrements a to 0
      -> calls f(0)
         -> prints "0"
         -> prints "0"
      -> prints "0"
   -> prints "1"
-> prints "2"
```

With the second code sample:

```
f(3)
-> prints "3"
-> calls f(2)
   -> prints "2"
   -> calls f(1)
      -> prints "1"
      -> calls f(0)
         -> prints "0"
         -> prints "0"
      -> prints "1"
   -> prints "2"
-> prints "3"
```

And the third sample code:

```
f(3)
-> prints "3"
-> *post*-decrements a to 2 
-> calls f(3)
   -> prints "3"
   -> *post*-decrements a to 2 
   -> calls f(3)
      -> Oops! Infinite loop.
```

Read up on [the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i) between pre- and post-increment and decrement operators.

Comment: Thank you for the visualisation :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if it helps.