# Increment behaviour using char pointer

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings, function-call, post-increment

When i write copy ( s1++, s2++ ) instead of copy ( ++s1, ++s2 ) nothing happens.What's the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void copy ( char *, char * );

int main ( void )
{
   char st[] = "hello";
   char st2[10];
   copy ( st, st2 ); 
   printf ( "%s", st2 );
}

void copy ( char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    *s2 = *s1;
    if ( *s1 == '\0' )
    {
        return;
    }
    copy ( ++s1, ++s2 );
}
```

Comment: `copy ( s1++, s2++ )` will repeatedly pass the *same* pointer values to the recursive calls of `copy`. That is, it is an infinete recursion doing the same thing over and over again (until the program presumably gets a stack overflow).

Comment: See [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853)

Comment: I'd say it would be clearer to write `copy (s1+1, s2+1);` as the recursive call

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
> operand.** As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
> incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
> it).

So using the post-increment operator you are calling recursively the function with the same values of the pointers.

This call

```
copy ( s1++, s2++ );
```

has the same effect as

```
copy ( s1, s2 );
++s1;
++s2;
```

Using the post-increment operator the function could be defined for example the following way.

```
void copy( const char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    if ( ( *s2++ = *s1++ ) ) copy( s1, s2 );
}
```

As for the prefix increment operator then according to the C Standard (6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented.
> **The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation**.