# C Program confusion Between x++ & ++x

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    printf("%d\n", ++x);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints out `2, 2`

But in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x++);
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

it prints out `1, 2`
why should it be `2, 1` since in the 1st `printf` statement we first assign value of `x` then it is increased means it should be `2` and in the 2nd `printf` statement the assigned value should be printed that is `1`. `2` is not assigned, why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: *"first assign value of x then it is increased"* - what do you mean by "assign value"? You aren't assigning a value to x, you are modifying it and the expression returns the old value of `x`

Comment: They both increment `x`.  But they are also expressions, and as such they produce a value.  The difference is that `++x` evaluates to the new `x`, while `x++` evaluates to the old `x`.  So `++x` is equivalent to `x += 1`, while `x++` is equivalent to `(temp = x, x += 1, temp)`.  You can test it with `t = x++;` and `t = ++x;`.  Both will have the same effect on `x`, but they will produce different values for `t`.

Comment: @UnholySheep may be my language is not so good but assign means value get updated or new value is stored in variable or variable value is changed.

Comment: What does returning value means. it may be a noobie question but i am new so i dont know very much

Comment: Read my comment again.  It fully explains it.  One more time:  Try `t = x++;` and `t = ++x;`  They both have the same effect on `x`, but produce different values for `t`.  Expressions produce a value.  In this case, `x++` produces the old value of `x` and `++x` produces the new value of `x`.  Those values are then used in the value of the expression.  You could also do things like `y + x++` vs. `y + ++x`.  Again, both expressions will have the same effect on `x`, but different values will be added to `y`.  Try it.  You were given concrete examples.  Run them.  This should not be confusing.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ok Thanq Man i got it finally :)